# Python: Get HTTP headers from urllib2.urlopen call?

Tags: python, urllib, forwarding

Does `urllib2` fetch the whole page when a `urlopen` call is made?

I'd like to just read the HTTP response header without getting the page. It looks like `urllib2` opens the HTTP connection and then subsequently gets the actual HTML page... or does it just start buffering the page with the `urlopen` call?

```
import urllib2
myurl = 'http://www.kidsidebyside.org/2009/05/come-and-draw-the-circle-of-unity-with-us/'
page = urllib2.urlopen(myurl) // open connection, get headers

html = page.readlines()  // stream page
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use the `response.info()` method to get the headers.

From the [urllib2 docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html):

> urllib2.urlopen(url[, data][, timeout])
>
> ...
>
> This function returns a file-like object with two additional methods:
>
> - geturl() — return the URL of the resource retrieved, commonly used to determine if a redirect was followed
> - info() — return the meta-information of the page, such as headers, in the form of an httplib.HTTPMessage instance (see Quick Reference to HTTP Headers)

So, for your example, try stepping through the result of `response.info().headers` for what you're looking for.

Note the major caveat to using httplib.HTTPMessage is documented in [python issue 4773](http://bugs.python.org/issue4773).

Comment: ***Python 3 Note*** First, there is nothing like `response.info().headers`, do a `dict(response.info())`. Second, for the HTTP status code do `response.status`.

Comment: Does this **only gets** the header or **only prints** the header?

Comment: Where is `headers` documented? Also consider using `response.info().items()` that returns a key value dict.

Comment: _**Python 2 Note**_ this is what you want: `response.info().getheader('Content-Type')` source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653591/python-urllib2-response-header

Comment: actually for Python 3: `response.headers` will do, for more info `http.client.HTTPResponse`

Answer (score 42):

What about sending a HEAD request instead of a normal GET request. The following snipped (copied from a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107405/how-do-you-send-a-head-http-request-in-python)) does exactly that.

```
>>> import httplib
>>> conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.google.com")
>>> conn.request("HEAD", "/index.html")
>>> res = conn.getresponse()
>>> print res.status, res.reason
200 OK
>>> print res.getheaders()
[('content-length', '0'), ('expires', '-1'), ('server', 'gws'), ('cache-control', 'private, max-age=0'), ('date', 'Sat, 20 Sep 2008 06:43:36 GMT'), ('content-type', 'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1')]
```

Answer (score 23):

Actually, it appears that urllib2 can do an HTTP HEAD request.

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107405/how-do-you-send-a-head-http-request-in-python) that @reto linked to, above, shows how to get urllib2 to do a HEAD request.

Here's my take on it:

```
import urllib2

# Derive from Request class and override get_method to allow a HEAD request.
class HeadRequest(urllib2.Request):
    def get_method(self):
        return "HEAD"

myurl = 'http://bit.ly/doFeT'
request = HeadRequest(myurl)

try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    response_headers = response.info()

    # This will just display all the dictionary key-value pairs.  Replace this
    # line with something useful.
    response_headers.dict

except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    # Prints the HTTP Status code of the response but only if there was a 
    # problem.
    print ("Error code: %s" % e.code)
```

If you check this with something like the Wireshark network protocol analazer, you can see that it is actually sending out a HEAD request, rather than a GET.

This is the HTTP request and response from the code above, as captured by Wireshark:

> HEAD /doFeT HTTP/1.1
>  Accept-Encoding: identity
>  Host:
>   bit.ly
>  Connection: close
>  User-Agent: Python-urllib/2.7
>
> HTTP/1.1 301 Moved
>  Server: nginx
>  Date: Sun, 19 Feb 2012
>   13:20:56 GMT
>  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
>   Cache-control: private; max-age=90
>  Location:
>   http://www.kidsidebyside.org/?p=445
>  MIME-Version: 1.0
>   Content-Length: 127
>  Connection: close
>  Set-Cookie:
>   _bit=4f40f738-00153-02ed0-421cf10a;domain=.bit.ly;expires=Fri Aug 17 13:20:56 2012;path=/; HttpOnly

However, as mentioned in one of the comments in the other question, if the URL in question includes a redirect then urllib2 will do a GET request to the destination, not a HEAD.  This could be a major shortcoming, if you really wanted to only make HEAD requests.

The request above involves a redirect.  Here is request to the destination, as captured by Wireshark:

> GET /2009/05/come-and-draw-the-circle-of-unity-with-us/ HTTP/1.1
>   Accept-Encoding: identity
>  Host: www.kidsidebyside.org
>   Connection: close
>  User-Agent: Python-urllib/2.7

An alternative to using urllib2 is to use Joe Gregorio's [httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/) library:

```
import httplib2

url = "http://bit.ly/doFeT"
http_interface = httplib2.Http()

try:
    response, content = http_interface.request(url, method="HEAD")
    print ("Response status: %d - %s" % (response.status, response.reason))

    # This will just display all the dictionary key-value pairs.  Replace this
    # line with something useful.
    response.__dict__

except httplib2.ServerNotFoundError, e:
    print (e.message)
```

This has the advantage of using HEAD requests for both the initial HTTP request and the redirected request to the destination URL.

Here's the first request:

> HEAD /doFeT HTTP/1.1
>  Host: bit.ly
>  accept-encoding: gzip,
>   deflate
>  user-agent: Python-httplib2/0.7.2 (gzip)

Here's the second request, to the destination:

> HEAD /2009/05/come-and-draw-the-circle-of-unity-with-us/ HTTP/1.1
>   Host: www.kidsidebyside.org
>  accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
>   user-agent: Python-httplib2/0.7.2 (gzip)

Comment: I missed it the first time I read the answer, but `response.info().dict` is exactly what I was looking for.  This is *not* explained [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/mimetools.html#mimetools.Message).

Answer (score 8):

urllib2.urlopen does an HTTP GET (or POST if you supply a data argument), not an HTTP HEAD (if it did the latter, you couldn't do readlines or other accesses to the page body, of course).

Answer (score 4):

One-liner:

```
$ python -c "import urllib2; print urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1)).open(urllib2.Request('http://google.com'))"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def _GetHtmlPage(self, addr):
  headers = { 'User-Agent' : self.userAgent,
            '  Cookie' : self.cookies}

  req = urllib2.Request(addr)
  response = urllib2.urlopen(req)

  print "ResponseInfo="
  print response.info()

  resultsHtml = unicode(response.read(), self.encoding)
  return resultsHtml
```