# Download a URL only if it is a HTML Webpage

Tags: python, download, html-parsing, beautifulsoup, printing-web-page

I want to write a python script which downloads the web-page only if the web-page contains HTML. I know that `content-type` in `header` will be used. Please suggest someway to do it as i am unable to get a way to get `header` before the file download.

Comment: @NiklasB. I have explored the request object and tried the retrieve function bu it creates a file on the file system first and returns the email.mimetype object. But i want to download the file only if the content is HTML

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843392/python-get-http-headers-from-urllib-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `http.client` to send a `HEAD` request to the URL. This will return only the headers for the resource then you can look at the `content-type` header and see if it `text/html`. If it is then send a `GET` request to the URL to get the body.