# Python: How to get the Content-Type of an URL?

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib

I need to get the content-type of an internet(intranet) resource not a local file.  How can I get the MIME type from a resource behind an URL:

I tried this:

```
res = urllib.urlopen("http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry")
http_message = res.info()
message = http_message.getplist()
```

I get:
`['charset=UTF-8']`

How can I get the `Content-Type`, can be done using `urllib` and how or if not what is the other way?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843392/python-get-http-headers-from-urllib-call

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21515813/538284

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
res = urllib.urlopen("http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry" )
http_message = res.info()
full = http_message.type # 'text/plain'
main = http_message.maintype # 'text'
```

Comment: what  to do if it gives 403 error?

Answer (score 31):

A Python3 solution to this:

```
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.google.com') as response:
    info = response.info()
    print(info.get_content_type())      # -> text/html
    print(info.get_content_maintype())  # -> text
    print(info.get_content_subtype())   # -> html
```

Answer (score 2):

Update: since info() function is deprecated in Python 3.9, you can read about the preferred type called headers [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage)

```
import urllib

r = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
header = r.headers                              # type is email.message.EmailMessage
contentType = header.get_content_type()         # or header.get('content-type')
contentLength = header.get('content-length')
filename = header.get_filename()
```

also, a good way to quickly get the mimetype without actually loading the url

```
import mimetypes
contentType, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(url)
```

The second method does not guarantee an answer but is a quick and dirty trick since it's just looking at the URL string rather than actually opening the URL.

Comment: res = urllib.urlopen("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474406/python-how-to-get-the-content-type-of-an-url" ) gives 403 error, is there any other workaround to get the content_type?

Comment: Try resquests library

import requests
r = requests.get("https://www.stackoverflow.com")
r.headers.get('content-type')