# How do I read the size of an archive on web

Tags: python

I want to download a file from a website using python (urllib or urllib2)
  While downloading I want to show the percentage of the download.

```
#!usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: latin1 -*-

import urllib

url = 'http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/pk2cmdv1-20Linux2-6.tar.gz'
urllib.urlretrieve(url, "pickit.tar.gz")
```

How could I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
def download(url, local_file):
    def progress(blocks_read, block_size, total_size):
        percent = min(int(blocks_read * block_size * 100 / total_size), 100)
        sys.stdout.write("\rdownloading {}: {:2}%".format(local_file, percent))
        if percent == 100:
            sys.stdout.write('\n')
        sys.stdout.flush()

    urllib.urlretrieve(url, local_file, reporthook=progress)


# call download function
download("http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/pk2cmdv1-20Linux2-6.tar.gz",
         "pickit.tar.gz")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "*urllib2.urlopen(..)*" instead and read the headers, it will contain the data you're looking for (content length)!

A good example: [Python: Get HTTP headers from urllib2.urlopen call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843392/python-get-http-headers-from-urllib-call)

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028517/python-urllib2-progress-hook) has an nice snippet.

In short:

1. get the content-length header
2. read a chunk of data
3. calc percentage
4. repeat 2 and 3 until done