# How to check filetype by url?

Tags: jquery

Users register url's (bookmarks) to my website. I'd like categorize url's depending on filetype whether they are HTML, image, etc. How can I detect the filetype if I can with HEAD request? Or any other solution?

Comment: If security is important, you have to check it server side. If no or just want to do a prefilter, you should be able to just use a regex or check by splitting string, e.g: `var extension = uri.split('.').pop();`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/843401/881224