# I am downloading a file using Python urllib2. How do I check how large the file size is?

Tags: python, file, download, urllib2

And if it is large...then stop the download?
I don't want to download files that are larger than 12MB.

```
request = urllib2.Request(ep_url)
request.add_header('User-Agent',random.choice(agents))
thefile = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's no need as [bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince) did and drop to httplib. You can do all that with urllib directly:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> f = urllib2.urlopen("http://dalkescientific.com")
>>> f.headers.items()
[('content-length', '7535'), ('accept-ranges', 'bytes'), ('server', 'Apache/2.2.14'),
 ('last-modified', 'Sun, 09 Mar 2008 00:27:43 GMT'), ('connection', 'close'),
 ('etag', '"19fa87-1d6f-447f627da7dc0"'), ('date', 'Wed, 28 Oct 2009 19:59:10 GMT'),
 ('content-type', 'text/html')]
>>> f.headers["Content-Length"]
'7535'
>>>
```

If you use httplib then you may have to implement redirect handling, proxy support, and the other nice things that urllib2 does for you.

Answer (score 7):

You could say:

```
maxlength= 12*1024*1024
thefile= urllib2.urlopen(request).read(maxlength+1)
if len(thefile)==maxlength+1:
    raise ThrowToysOutOfPramException()
```

but then of course you've still read 12MB of unwanted data. If you want to minimise the risk of this happening you can check the HTTP Content-Length header, if present (it might not be). But to do that you need to drop down to [httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html) instead of the more general urllib.

```
u= urlparse.urlparse(ep_url)
cn= httplib.HTTPConnection(u.netloc)
cn.request('GET', u.path, headers= {'User-Agent': ua})
r= cn.getresponse()

try:
    l= int(r.getheader('Content-Length', '0'))
except ValueError:
    l= 0
if l>maxlength:
    raise IAmCrossException()

thefile= r.read(maxlength+1)
if len(thefile)==maxlength+1:
    raise IAmStillCrossException()
```

You can check the length before asking to get the file too, if you prefer. This is basically the same as above, except using the method `'HEAD'` instead of `'GET'`.

Comment: This is a better solution, since Content-Length is not reliable (Someone may incorrectly set it)

Answer (score 1):

you can check the content-length in a HEAD request first, but be warned, this header doesn't have to be set - see [How do you send a HEAD HTTP request in Python 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107405/how-do-you-send-a-head-http-request-in-python)

Comment: How do I check the content-length in the HEAD request? Is this considered downloading headers?

Comment: Doing a HEAD request is at best theoretical if you want to use urllib/urllib2. Those modules only support GET and POST requests.

Answer (score 1):

This will work if the Content-Length header is set

```
import urllib2          
req = urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com/file.zip")
total_size = int(req.info().getheader('Content-Length'))
```

Comment: you don't need `.strip()`: 1. `getheader()` already returns stripped version 2. `int()` doesn't care about leading/trailing whitespace.

Comment: Also, there is no point to use `int(info().getheader())` if you don't set the default value: `ValueError` from `int` is less appropriate than `KeyError` from `req.headers` (note: `req.info() is req.headers`)

Comment: @Gourneau - Would this still work if the url specified is ftp:// url?

Comment: @PankajParashar Nope, "Content-Length" is pulled out of the HTTP header, so only works with HTTP. This might be what you need though http://stackoverflow.com/a/5241914/56069