# Python ftplib can't get size of file before download?

Tags: python, ftplib

I'm using ftplib to transfer files.  Everything is working great.  Now I'm trying to get the size of the target file before downloading.

1. First, I tried just getting size with ftp.size(filename).  Server complained that I can't do that in ascii mode.
2. Then I tried setting binary mode using ftp.sendcmd("binary") and ftp.sendcmd("bin").  In both cases the server complained "500 binary Not understood"

Can ftplib get size of a file before downloading in this instance?  I don't control the FTP server and can't change how it's behaving.

Thanks

Answer (score 27):

Very late reply, but here's the correct answer. This works with ProFTPD.

```
ftp.sendcmd("TYPE i")    # Switch to Binary mode
ftp.size("/some/file")   # Get size of file
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness: to switch back to ASCII use `TYPE A`

Comment: works with pyftpdlib server too

Answer (score 4):

Ftplib can get the size of a file before downloading. As the documentation says:

> FTP.size(filename)
>   Request the size of
>   the file named filename on the server.
>   On success, the size of the file is
>   returned as an integer, otherwise None
>   is returned. **Note that the SIZE
>   command is not standardized, but is
>   upported by many common server
>   implementations**

Apparently your server doesn't support this feature.

Answer (score 0):

"Server complained that I can't do that in ascii mode." -- Try showing the exact code that you used AND the exact text of the server response. Use copy/paste, don't type from memory.

Do you have access to a command-line FTP client? If not, get one. Use it to experiment with what the server can do. A client command like REMOTEHELP is your friend. Example:

```
ftp> remotehelp size
214 Syntax: SIZE <sp> pathname
```

This indicates that the server to which I was connected will support a SIZE command.