# `document.lastModified` in Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

In python, by using an HTML parser, is it possible to get the `document.lastModified` property of a web page. I'm trying to retrieve the date at which the webpage/document was last modified by the owner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A somewhat related question "[I am downloading a file using Python urllib2. How do I check how large the file size is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636637/i-am-downloading-a-file-using-python-urllib2-how-do-i-check-how-large-the-file)", suggests that the following (untested) code should work:

```
import urllib2          
req = urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com/file.zip")
total_size = int(req.info().getheader('last-modified'))
```

You might want to add a default value as the second parameter to `getheader()`, in case it isn't set.

Answer (score 1):

You can also look for a `last-modified` date in the HTML code, most notably in the `meta`-tags. The [htmldate](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/113237/when-you-should-not-use-regular-expressions) module does just that.

Here is how it could work:

**1. Install the package:**

```
pip/pip3/pipenv (your choice) -U htmldate
```

**2. Retrieve a web page, parse it and output the date:**

```
from htmldate import find_date

find_date('http://blog.python.org/2016/12/python-360-is-now-available.html')
```

*(disclaimer: I'm the author)*

Comment: Nice answer. Could you provide a sample of code in plain text to illustrate this approach? I invite you to read this guide to improve your question [answer]

Comment: Thank you for the input! I added further instructions.