# Script to validate domains

Tags: python, sockets, file-io, dns

Objective is to read a list of domains from a file and perform lookup to confirm reachability and resolution from my end.

This is what I have written:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import socket

f = open('file1.lst', 'r')
s = f.readlines()

for i in s:
    print i
    socket.gethostbyname(i.strip())

f.close()
```

`socket.gethostbyname()` line throws an exception.

Comment: @Simon adding i.strip() makes this work. But as soon as it encounters an inexistent domain or one that couldn't be resolved, it throws an exception & breaks out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for i in s:
    print i
    try:
        socket.gethostbyname(i.strip())
    except socket.gaierror:
        print "unable to get address for", i
```

If an address could not be found, then `gethostbyname` *will* raise an exception (not throw).  This is the way error handling is done in Python.  If you know how to properly deal with the error, the you should catch it with an `except` clause.

Note that you will need some more code to also check for connectivity.

Comment: +1. One question though, while reading up on exceptions, I saw we can also use else clause. What'd be the diff b/w else & except?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855759/python-try-else) for a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I wrote to do the same thing. It may be of use to you:

```
import argparse
from socket import getaddrinfo

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Check for validity of domains in list exported from exchange', version='%(prog)s 1.0')
    parser.add_argument('infile', nargs='+', type=str, help='list of input files')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Read domains from file
    domains = []
    for f in args.infile:
        with open(f, 'rt') as data:
            for line in data.readlines():
                split = line.replace('\x00',"").split(':')
                if split[0].strip() == 'Domain':
                    domains.append(split[1].strip())

    # Check each domain
    for domain in domains:
        try:
            getaddrinfo(domain, None)
        except Exception, e:
            print "Unable to resolve:", domain
```

Note that my input file has a slightly different format than yours, so you will need to adjust the input section.

Comment: Catching `Exception` is not usually a good idea as it is almost every possible exception in the system, and can hide other problems.  You probably want to catch either `socket.gaierror` or `socket.error`.

Comment: Thanks @Spencer. The exception handling block was quite useful. On a separate note, I guess you could've used gethostbyname() in your script too.

Comment: @Ethan, I was using 'Exception' initially, but after reading your comments, I looked into other exception keywords as well. My script gives a gaierror, so I included this instead of 'exception', eventually. Thanks

Comment: @Ethan Furman At the time I wrote this, I just needed a quick short script to check for legitimacy of domains. I only cared about domains it had a problem resolving, and I wasn't particular about why. However, I do agree that a more thorough script should only catch specific exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the string `'i'` to gethostbyname() rather than the variable `i`.

It should be `socket.gethostbyname(i)`

This question may be of use: [Checking if a website is up via Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949318/checking-if-a-website-is-up-via-python)

Comment: Thnx but just keeping - i - there was still giving an error because of trailing cr \ \n in the input.

Comment: Thanks for the link to check if website is up. I will check it out.

Comment: Yes, if you're iterating over lines in a file, you need to strip the new-lines.

Answer (score 1):

The `gethostbyname` line should be

```
socket.gethostbyname(i.strip())
```

with no quotes around the `i` variable. The `strip()` is to remove trailing lf \ cr characters which will cause an error.

Note: This will only verify that the domain exists in the DNS system, not that it is reachable / running. For that you will have to actuallyopen a connection to the remote host, on a port it is listening on,

Comment: adding i.strip() makes this work. But as soon as it encounters an inexistent domain or one that couldn't be resolved, it throws an exception & breaks out.

Comment: You need to handle the exception. This page explains try..except http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Exceptions

Answer (score 0):

```
import argparse
from socket import getaddrinfo

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Check for validity of domains in list exported from exchange', version='%(prog)s 1.0')
    parser.add_argument('infile', nargs='+', type=str, help='list of input files')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Read domains from file
    domains = []
    for f in args.infile:
        with open(f, 'rt') as data:
            for line in data.readlines():
                split = line.replace('\x00',"").split(':')
                if split[0].strip() == 'Domain':
                    domains.append(split[1].strip())

    # Check each domain
    for domain in domains:
        try:
            getaddrinfo(domain, None)
        except Exception, e:
            print "Unable to resolve:", domain
```

Comment: For future answers, don't just post code, add an explanation of what you're answering, how your answer solves OPs problem or what you've changed to fix OP's problem.