# What is the equivalent command for docker port CONTAINER in docker-py

Tags: python, docker, dockerpy

I trying to automate a docker server using docker-py. Need to check whether the host URL is pinging or not using python. Hence I need an **equivalent command** in python for `docker port container`.
`docker port container_id`

```
import docker
client = docker.from_env()
print(client.port('c03ebfb53a7d', 80))
```

Comment: Try [port](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/blob/master/docker/api/container.py#L879).

Comment: Is this your suggestion ?
client = docker.from_env()
print(client.port('c03ebfb53a7d', 80))

Comment: Based on source code, yes.

Comment: but it return 'DockerClient' object has no attribute 'port'

Comment: Can you give a demo

Comment: import docker is the module am using

Comment: My question is updated with code Please have a look. Whether I am right or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When instantiating `DockerClient` object whether through `docker.DockerClient(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock')` or `docker.from_env()`, inside constructor [`APIClient` object is instantiated](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/blob/master/docker/client.py#L40):

```py
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.api = APIClient(*args, **kwargs)
```

[`APIClient` itself is inheriting a bunch of classes](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/blob/master/docker/api/client.py#L49):

```py
class APIClient(
    requests.Session,
    BuildApiMixin,
    ConfigApiMixin,
    ContainerApiMixin,
    DaemonApiMixin,
    ExecApiMixin,
    ImageApiMixin,
    NetworkApiMixin,
    PluginApiMixin,
    SecretApiMixin,
    ServiceApiMixin,
    SwarmApiMixin,
    VolumeApiMixin)
```

One of the classes it inherits is [`ContainerApiMixin`](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/blob/master/docker/api/container.py) that exposes methods for interacting with containers, similar to [`docker container`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container/) CLI.

As you can see, everything you can do through CLI is accessible through `api` object inside `DockerClient` object.

So, the answer to your question is:

```py
client.api.port('<container_id>', <port>)
```

---

**Resource**: [source code](https://github.com/docker/docker-py)

Comment: In addition to this, I need to verify whether the URL is reachable or not. I

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1949360/4778343)? Or something different?

Comment: `host=cli.port(id, 80)
    port=host[0]['HostPort']
    ip=host[0]['HostIp']
    server_ip=ip+':'+port
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
    rep = os.system('ping ' + server_ip)
    if rep == 0:
        print ('server is up')
    else:
        print ('server is down')`

Comment: I need to check whether it is reachable or not That is my ultimate purpose

Comment: Code is not showing any syntax error. But it always show the server error

Comment: Even I tried ping '0.0.0.0:8060' it also outcome the same in Linux terminal

Comment: `ping` does not work with ports. Use netcat instead: `os.system('nc -z ' + ip + ' ' + port)`.

Comment: how to check whether the space utilization is proper in servers using python (need to automate using docker-py)

Comment: Can you explain what do you need?

Comment: I need to verify whether the mounting space of containers is proper or not. If the space utilization is wrong then I will execute `docker system prune`

Comment: Need to implement this using python docker-py

Comment: But what do you mean by "_mounting space of containers is proper or not_"?

Comment: I need to check whether the space utilization of volumes mounted for the container is proper or not?

Comment: Or could you help me to know how to check the API testing in docker

Comment: It seems to be that all that depends on type of volume. Named volumes are stored under `/var/lib/docker` so it can grow up to total amount of free memory on the machine. Bind mounts are mounting points on the host, so they can grow up to total amount of free memory on the host. And finally there is `tmpfs` which is mounted in RAM memory and it can grow up to total amount of free RAM memory. I'm not sure how to inspect type of volume using Docker CLI, so you have to do a research yourself or ask another question on SO.