# What are the differences between the urllib, urllib2, urllib3 and requests module?

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib, urllib2, urllib3

In Python, what are the differences between the [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html), [`urllib2`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib2.html), [`urllib3`](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io) modules? Why are there three? They seem to do the same thing...

Comment: This question should be updated to clarify that `urllib` in Python 3 is yet another option, cleaned up in various ways. But thankfully the official documentation also notes that "_The Requests package is recommended for a higher-level HTTP client interface._" at [21.6. urllib.request — Extensible library for opening URLs — Python 3.6.3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html)

Comment: Saddly I didn't see any answers telling me what `urllib3` is and how `urllib3` is different from the official `urllib` module.

Comment: probably worth mentioning [httpx](https://github.com/encode/httpx) — the newer requests-backwords-compatible async library.

Answer (score 875, accepted):

I know it's been said already, but I'd highly recommend the [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) Python package.

If you've used languages other than python, you're probably thinking `urllib` and `urllib2` are easy to use, not much code, and highly capable, that's how I used to think.  But the `requests` package is so unbelievably useful and short that everyone should be using it.

First, it supports a fully restful API, and is as easy as:

```
import requests

resp = requests.get('http://www.mywebsite.com/user')
resp = requests.post('http://www.mywebsite.com/user')
resp = requests.put('http://www.mywebsite.com/user/put')
resp = requests.delete('http://www.mywebsite.com/user/delete')
```

Regardless of whether GET / POST, you never have to encode parameters again, it simply takes a dictionary as an argument and is good to go:

```
userdata = {"firstname": "John", "lastname": "Doe", "password": "jdoe123"}
resp = requests.post('http://www.mywebsite.com/user', data=userdata)
```

Plus it even has a built in JSON decoder (again, I know `json.loads()` isn't a lot more to write, but this sure is convenient):

```
resp.json()
```

Or if your response data is just text, use:

```
resp.text
```

This is just the tip of the iceberg. This is the list of features from the requests site:

- International Domains and URLs
- Keep-Alive & Connection Pooling
- Sessions with Cookie Persistence
- Browser-style SSL Verification
- Basic/Digest Authentication
- Elegant Key/Value Cookies
- Automatic Decompression
- Unicode Response Bodies
- Multipart File Uploads
- Connection Timeouts
- .netrc support
- List item
- Python 2.7, 3.6—3.9
- Thread-safe.

Comment: It would help to note that the Python 3 documentation has yet another distinct library `urllib` and that its documentation also officially notes that "_The Requests package is recommended for a higher-level HTTP client interface._" at [21.6. urllib.request — Extensible library for opening URLs — Python 3.6.3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html), and that `urllib3` is a great library used by `requests`.

Comment: Ok except I have the impression [request has no replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28328919/673991) for `urllib.parse()`

Comment: I don't understand why this is the accepted answer. It didn't answer OP's question.

Comment: @TylerCrompton technically, yes, but the implication is that the `urllib` packages are less user-friendly

Comment: @TylerCrompton Because it answers the real question - which one to use?

Comment: Really this answer is just propaganda and it is not useful to answer the OP Question

Answer (score 274):

In the Python 2 standard library there were two HTTP libraries that existed side-by-side. Despite the similar name, they were unrelated: they had a different design and a different implementation.

- [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) was the original Python HTTP client, added to the standard library in [Python 1.2](https://www.python.org/download/releases/). Earlier documentation for `urllib` can be found in [Python 1.4](https://docs.python.org/release/1.4/lib/node113.html).
- [`urllib2`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) was a more capable HTTP client, [added in Python 1.6](https://www.python.org/download/releases/1.6/#news), intended as a replacement for `urllib`:

  > urllib2 - new and improved but incompatible version of urllib (still experimental).

  Earlier documentation for `urllib2` can be found in [Python 2.1](https://docs.python.org/release/2.1/lib/module-urllib2.html).

The Python 3 standard library has a [**new** `urllib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html) which is a merged/refactored/rewritten version of the older modules.

[`urllib3`](https://pypi.org/project/urllib3) is a third-party package (i.e., not in CPython's standard library). Despite the name, it is unrelated to the standard library packages, and there is no intention to include it in the standard library in the future.

Finally, [`requests`](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) internally uses `urllib3`, but it aims for an easier-to-use API.

Comment: Great answer, now I have another reason to not use requests, and be more confident when using the new `urllib`. Is there any discussion/announcement about the change and enhancement of the new `urllib`? I didn't find any but is really interested in knowing more about it.

Comment: Thank you! The accepted answer doesn't answer the OP's question at all, just promotes the use of the requests lib.

Comment: @Reorx the changes from Python 2's `urllib`/`urllib2` to Python 3's "new" `urllib` seem to be mostly a part of the 2-to-3 standard library reorganization project as documented in [PEP 3108](https://peps.python.org/pep-3108/); it wasn't really about enhancements (as in, for example, new features), though I guess there have been many improvements over the years since 3.0.

Answer (score 229):

urllib2 provides some extra functionality, namely the `urlopen()` function can allow you to specify headers (normally you'd have had to use httplib in the past, which is far more verbose.) More importantly though, urllib2 provides the `Request` class, which allows for a more declarative approach to doing a request:

```
r = Request(url='http://www.mysite.com')
r.add_header('User-Agent', 'awesome fetcher')
r.add_data(urllib.urlencode({'foo': 'bar'})
response = urlopen(r)
```

Note that `urlencode()` is only in urllib, not urllib2.

There are also handlers for implementing more advanced URL support in urllib2.  The short answer is, unless you're working with legacy code, you probably want to use the URL opener from urllib2, but you still need to import into urllib for some of the utility functions.

**Bonus answer**
With Google App Engine, you can use any of httplib, urllib or urllib2, but all of them are just wrappers for Google's URL Fetch API. That is, you are still subject to the same limitations such as ports, protocols, and the length of the response allowed. You can use the core of the libraries as you would expect for retrieving HTTP URLs, though.

Comment: How does somebody create a url with an encoded query string using urllib2? It's the only reason I'm using urllib and I'd like to make sure I'm doing everything the latest/greatest way.

Comment: Like in my above example, you use `urlopen()` and `Request` from *urllib2*, and you use `urlencode()` from *urllib*. No real harm in using both libraries, as long as you make sure you use the correct urlopen.  The [urllib docs][1] are clear on that using this is acecepted usage.

  [1]: http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen

Comment: I used [this](https://gist.github.com/vgoklani/1811970) gist for `urllib2.urlopen` ; contains other variations too.

Comment: urllib2 does not support put or delete which is a pain

Comment: `requests` also allow custom headers: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers

Answer (score 68):

**urllib** and **urllib2** are both Python modules that do URL request related stuff but offer different functionalities.

1) urllib2 can accept a Request object to set the headers for a URL request, urllib accepts only a URL.

2) urllib provides the **urlencode** method which is used for the generation of GET query strings, urllib2 doesn't have such a function. This is one of the reasons why urllib is often used along with urllib2.

**Requests** - Requests’ is a simple, easy-to-use HTTP library written in Python.

1) Python Requests encodes the parameters automatically so you just pass them as simple arguments, unlike in the case of urllib, where you need to use the method **urllib.encode()** to encode the parameters before passing them.

2) It automatically decoded the response into Unicode.

3) Requests also has far more convenient error handling.If your authentication failed, urllib2 would raise a urllib2.URLError, while Requests would return a normal response object, as expected. All you have to see if the request was successful by boolean **response.ok**

Comment: what about urllib3?

Comment: @PirateApp [requests](https://github.com/psf/requests/) is built on top of [urllib3](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3). I think code using urllib3 directly can be more efficient, because it lets you reuse the session, whereas requests (at least requests 2, the one everyone uses) creates one for every request, but don't quote me on that. Neither are part of the standard library ([yet](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/2424))

Answer (score 40):

Just to add to the existing answers, I don't see anyone mentioning that python requests is not a native library. If you are ok with adding dependencies, then requests is fine. However, if you are trying to avoid adding dependencies, urllib is a native python library that is already available to you.

Comment: True, if you want to avoid adding any dependencies, urllib is available. But note that even the [Python official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request) recommends the requests library: "The Requests package is recommended for a higher-level HTTP client interface."

Comment: @hlongmore Of course, most people wouldn't want to deal with low level urllib, and Requests library provides a nice level of abstraction. It's like using a pancake mix in a box versus making it from scratch. Pros and cons.

Answer (score 16):

One considerable difference is about porting Python2 to Python3. urllib2 does not exist for python3 and its methods ported to urllib.
So you are using that heavily and want to migrate to Python3 in future, consider using urllib.
However 2to3 tool will automatically do most of the work for you.

Comment: Can you please go more into detail? If urllib2 does not exist on python3 anymore, was it removed or renamed? And why did that happen, do you have any external link?

Answer (score 16):

I think all answers are pretty good. But fewer details about urllib3.urllib3 is a very powerful HTTP client for python.
For installing both of the following commands will work,

### `urllib3`

using pip,

```
pip install urllib3
```

or you can get the latest code from Github and install them using,

```
$ git clone git://github.com/urllib3/urllib3.git
$ cd urllib3
$ python setup.py install
```

Then you are ready to go,

Just import urllib3 using,

```
import urllib3
```

In here, Instead of creating a connection directly, You’ll need a PoolManager instance to make requests. This handles connection pooling and thread-safety for you. There is also a ProxyManager object for routing requests through an HTTP/HTTPS proxy
Here you can refer to the documentation.
example usage :

```
>>> from urllib3 import PoolManager
>>> manager = PoolManager(10)
>>> r = manager.request('GET', 'http://google.com/')
>>> r.headers['server']
'gws'
>>> r = manager.request('GET', 'http://yahoo.com/')
>>> r.headers['server']
'YTS/1.20.0'
>>> r = manager.request('POST', 'http://google.com/mail')
>>> r = manager.request('HEAD', 'http://google.com/calendar')
>>> len(manager.pools)
2
>>> conn = manager.connection_from_host('google.com')
>>> conn.num_requests
3
```

As mentioned in `urrlib3` documentations,`urllib3` brings many critical features that are missing from the Python standard libraries.

- Thread safety.
- Connection pooling.
- Client-side SSL/TLS verification.
- File uploads with multipart encoding.
- Helpers for retrying requests and dealing with HTTP redirects.
- Support for gzip and deflate encoding.
- Proxy support for HTTP and SOCKS.
- 100% test coverage.

Follow the user guide for more details.

- [Response content](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#response-content) (The HTTPResponse object provides status, data,
  and header attributes)
- [Using io Wrappers with Response content](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#using-io-wrappers-with-response-content)
- [Creating a query parameter](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#query-parameters)
- [Advanced usage of urllib3](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html)

### `requests`

requests uses `urllib3` under the hood and make it even simpler to make `requests` and retrieve data.
For one thing, keep-alive is 100% automatic, compared to `urllib3` where it's not. It also has event hooks which call a callback function when an event is triggered, like receiving a response
In `requests`, each request type has its own function. So instead of creating a connection or a pool, you directly GET a URL.

---

For install `requests` using pip just run

`pip install requests`

or you can just install from source code,

```
$ git clone git://github.com/psf/requests.git
$ cd requests
$ python setup.py install
```

Then, `import requests`

Here you can refer the official [documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request),
For some advanced usage like session object, SSL verification, and Event Hooks please refer to this [url](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/).

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I came here because I had seen `urllib3` and didn't know if I should use it or `requests`. Now I feel informed about how to make that decision going forward. The accepted answer gives a nice breakdown of `requests` but does not differentiate it from the alternatives.

Comment: If you are afflicted by a corporate proxy, know that the requests module cheerfully honors environment variables http_proxy, https_proxy, no_proxy. The urllib3 module ignores environment variables; to send your queries via a proxy you must create an instance of ProxyManager instead of PoolManager.

Answer (score 12):

I like the `urllib.urlencode` function, and it doesn't appear to exist in `urllib2`.

```
>>> urllib.urlencode({'abc':'d f', 'def': '-!2'})
'abc=d+f&def=-%212'
```

Comment: Just a note, be careful with urlencode as it can't handle <unicode>  objects directly -- you have to encode them before sending them to urlencode (u'blá'.encode('utf-8'), or whatever).

Comment: @user18015: I do not think this applies to Python 3, can you clarify?

Comment: As I noted above, this question and the various answers should be updated to clarify that `urllib` in Python 3 is yet another option, cleaned up in various ways. But thankfully, the official documentation also notes that "_The Requests package is recommended for a higher-level HTTP client interface._" at [21.6. urllib.request — Extensible library for opening URLs — Python 3.6.3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html)

Comment: urllib2 doesn't exist at all in Python 3

Comment: It moved to urllib.parse.urlencode in Python 3.

Answer (score 10):

To get the content of a url:

```
try: # Try importing requests first.
    import requests
except ImportError: 
    try: # Try importing Python3 urllib
        import urllib.request
    except AttributeError: # Now importing Python2 urllib
        import urllib


def get_content(url):
    try:  # Using requests.
        return requests.get(url).content # Returns requests.models.Response.
    except NameError:  
        try: # Using Python3 urllib.
            with urllib.request.urlopen(index_url) as response:
                return response.read() # Returns http.client.HTTPResponse.
        except AttributeError: # Using Python3 urllib.
            return urllib.urlopen(url).read() # Returns an instance.
```

It's hard to write Python2 and Python3 and `request` dependencies code for the responses because they `urlopen()` functions and `requests.get()` function return different types:

- Python2 `urllib.request.urlopen()` returns a `http.client.HTTPResponse`
- Python3 `urllib.urlopen(url)` returns an `instance`
- Request `request.get(url)` returns a `requests.models.Response`

Answer (score 6):

You should generally use urllib2, since this makes things a bit easier at times by accepting Request objects and will also raise a URLException on protocol errors. With Google App Engine though, you can't use either. You have to use the [URL Fetch API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/) that Google provides in its sandboxed Python environment.

Comment: What you said about appengine is not entirely true. You can actually use httplib, urllib, and urllib2 in App Engine now (they are wrappers for url fetch, done so that more code would be compatible with appengine.)

Comment: Ah, must be new. My code failed last I tried and had to be rewritten to work with fetch...

Comment: https://devsite.googleplex.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview#Fetching_URLs_in_Python

Comment: urllib2 doesn't exist at all in Python 3

Comment: @Boris It migrated to [urllib.request](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) and [urllib.error](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.error.html).

Answer (score 5):

A key point that I find missing in the above answers is that urllib returns an object of type `<class http.client.HTTPResponse>` whereas `requests` returns `<class 'requests.models.Response'>`.

Due to this, read() method can be used with `urllib` but not with `requests`.

P.S. : `requests` is already rich with so many methods that it hardly needs one more as `read()` ;>