# Java equivalent of Pythons urllib.urlencode(HashMap based UrlEncode)

Tags: java, python, url, encoding, urlencode

[From](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018026/should-i-use-urllib-or-urllib2/2018103#2018103)

Whats the java equivalent of Python’s urllib.urlencode?
Like

```
>>> urllib.urlencode({'abc':'d f', 'def': '-!2'})
'abc=d+f&def=-%212'
```

Where I can pass a HashMap of key values and it encodes and gives me the url string ..

***Edit:*** I wanted to avoid this scenario

```
String data = URLEncoder.encode("key1", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("value1", "UTF-8");
    data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("key2", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("value2", "UTF-8");
```

of manually concatenating the strings with

> =

and

> &

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[java.net.URLEncoder](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) should work for you - though you would have to extend it to accept the hashmap - but that is not very difficult.

Comment: Yes - you can avoid that by using a hashmap and a loop :)