# python: check if url to jpg exists

Tags: python, url, validation

In python, how would I check if a url ending in .jpg exists?

ex:
http://www.fakedomain.com/fakeImage.jpg

thanks

Comment: Please give details by editing the question description to address these points: What qualifies as "exists"? How does it differ from "an HTTP GET request to that URL succeeds"?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
>>> import httplib
>>>
>>> def exists(site, path):
...     conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(site)
...     conn.request('HEAD', path)
...     response = conn.getresponse()
...     conn.close()
...     return response.status == 200
...
>>> exists('http://www.fakedomain.com', '/fakeImage.jpg')
False
```

If the status is anything other than a 200, the resource doesn't exist at the URL. This doesn't mean that it's gone altogether. If the server returns a 301 or 302, this means that the resource still exists, but at a different URL. To alter the function to handle this case, the status check line just needs to be changed to `return response.status in (200, 301, 302)`.

Comment: +1, although I'd imagine using `HEAD` instead of `GET` in the call to `conn.request` would be more efficient, since you're only checking to see if it exists.

Comment: @Daniel, thanks for that tip.  I've updated the code to use HEAD.

Comment: If you are seeing errors similar to: **"gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known"** make sure that your 'site' value does not include `http://`, `ftp://`, etc. Instead it seems that httplib will attempt to derive the correct protocol or requires the appropriate port number to be specified (see additional comment below).

Comment: Furthermore, if you get the error **"InvalidURL: nonnumeric port: '//www.fakedomain.com'"**, make sure you add the appropriate port number to your 'site' URL. In my case, this meant changing `http://www.fakedomain.com` to `www.fakedomain.com:80` which solved this issue.

Indeed in reviewing the documentation for httplib on python.org, I noticed that the examples listed exclude the protocol definition from the URL: http://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018026/should-i-use-urllib-or-urllib2-or-requests for a comparison of the different libs that could be used for this. Requests seems to be the most popular.

Comment: does it work for this url http://www.hdwallpapers4ipad.com/_ph/13/426699792.jpg I have found they can add as a .jpg and not actually be an image.

Comment: In some cases you can get a 405 (method not allowed). In this case, you may use a GET as new try.

Answer (score 53):

The code below is equivalent to [tikiboy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2486412/596361), but using a high-level and easy-to-use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library.

```
import requests

def exists(path):
    r = requests.head(path)
    return r.status_code == requests.codes.ok

print exists('http://www.fakedomain.com/fakeImage.jpg')
```

The `requests.codes.ok` equals `200`, so you can substitute the exact status code if you wish.

`requests.head` may throw an [exception](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/?highlight=exception#requests.exceptions.ConnectionError) if server doesn't respond, so you might want to add a try-except construct.

Also if you want to include codes `301` and `302`, consider code `303` too, especially if you [dereference URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereferenceable_Uniform_Resource_Identifier) that denote resources in [Linked Data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_Data). A URI may represent a person, but you can't download a person, so the server will redirect you to a page that describes this person using [303 redirect](http://linkeddatabook.com/editions/1.0/#htoc12).

Comment: This answer looks the simplest and the most normal way to do this now. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018026/should-i-use-urllib-or-urllib2-or-requests

Comment: Works perfectly in Python 3.5 opposite to other answers.

Comment: `[ 301, 302, 303, 307, 308, 200 ]` 
should be the correct codes to look for according to [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42138726/3967709)

Answer (score 7):

thanks for all the responses everyone, ended up using the following:

```
try:
  f = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(url))
  deadLinkFound = False
except:
  deadLinkFound = True
```

Comment: Short n' sweet. I used this myself as my URL string(s) (about 5000 of them) were the full URI --I didn't want to get too detailed. I was also able to assume that i'd receive a 404 and not a redirect. Not sure it this would work with a redirect.

Comment: Well, will give True on URL errors also and even on 301,302,303 errors also.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like `http://www.fakedomain.com/fakeImage.jpg` automatically redirected to `http://www.fakedomain.com/index.html` without any error.

Redirecting for 301 and 302 responses are automatically done without giving any response back to user.

Please take a look [HTTPRedirectHandler](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#httpredirecthandler-objects), you might need to subclass it to handle that.

Here is the one sample from Dive Into Python:

http://diveintopython3.ep.io/http-web-services.html#redirects

Comment: I think fakedomain.com is used for example as named and actually you needn't to visit it yourself.:-)

Comment: @SpawnCxy, At first I thought like that, but when I go to that url, 
fakeImage.jpg does not exist and its redirected to index.html, so I am assuming its more than an example.

Answer (score 4):

There are problems with the previous answers when the file is in ftp server (ftp://url.com/file), the following code works when the file is in ftp, http or https:

```
import urllib2

def file_exists(url):
    request = urllib2.Request(url)
    request.get_method = lambda : 'HEAD'
    try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

Comment: I couldn't get any of the previous answers to return False when I entered a bad file URL, but this answer worked great!

Comment: Is there a way to do same thing with urllib3?

Comment: not exactly like this, for urllib3 requires some changes

Answer (score 2):

Try it with [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/):

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_redirect(False)
try:
 br.open_novisit('http://www.fakedomain.com/fakeImage.jpg')
 print 'OK'
except:
 print 'KO'
```

Comment: https://kite.com/python/docs/mechanize.Browser.open_novisit says, it doesn't send response - It has to send a response right ?

Answer (score 1):

This might be good enough to see if a url to a file exists.

```
import urllib
if urllib.urlopen('http://www.fakedomain.com/fakeImage.jpg').code == 200:
  print 'File exists'
```

Answer (score 0):

in Python 3.6.5:

```
import http.client

def exists(site, path):
    connection =  http.client.HTTPConnection(site)
    connection.request('HEAD', path)
    response = connection.getresponse()
    connection.close()
    return response.status == 200

exists("www.fakedomain.com", "/fakeImage.jpg")
```

In Python 3, the module `httplib` has been renamed to `http.client`

And you need remove the `http://` and `https://` from your URL, because the `httplib` is considering `:` as a port number and the port number must be numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Python3

```
import requests

def url_exists(url):
    """Check if resource exist?"""
    if not url:
        raise ValueError("url is required")
    try:
        resp = requests.head(url)
        return True if resp.status_code == 200 else False
    except Exception as e:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @z3moon was good, but I think it is for py 2.x. For python 3.x, you may want to add `request` to the module call.

```py
import urllib
def check_valid_URLs(url) -> bool:
  try:
    if urllib.request.urlopen(url).code == 200:
      return True
    else:
      return False
  except:
    return False
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can try send a http request to the url and read the response.If no exception was caught,it probably exists.

Comment: that's what I tried doing but I couldn't find any specific code samples. Would you happen to have one?