# What's the difference between HTTP 301 and 308 status codes?

Tags: http, http-status-code-301, http-status-codes, http-status-code-308

What's the difference between HTTP `301` and `308` status codes?

- `301` (Moved Permanently): This and all future requests should be directed to the given URI.
- `308` (Permanent Redirect): The request and all future requests should be repeated using another URI.

They seem to be similar.

Comment: No code 308 in https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616 and https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6585, so the question has to be addressed to the inventor of this non-standard code.

Comment: There is specification RFC 7538, therefore it is real HTTP code

Comment: Well, https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7538: Note: This status code is similar to 301, except that it does not allow changing the request method from POST to GET.

Comment: Don't use the RFC 2616 as reference. It was obsoleted by the RFCs 7230-35.

Comment: And the RFCs 7230-35 have now been obsoleted by the RFCs 9110-12.

Answer (score 463, accepted):

### An overview of `301`, `302` and `307`

The [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231), the current reference for semantics and content of the HTTP/1.1 protocol, defines the [`301`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.2) (Moved Permanently) and [`302`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.3) (Found) status code, that allows the request method to be changed from `POST` to `GET`. This specification also defines the [`307`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.7) (Temporary Redirect) status code that doesn't allow the request method to be changed from `POST` to `GET`.

See more details below:

> [**6.4.2.  301 Moved Permanently**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.2)
>
> The `301` (Moved Permanently) status code indicates that the target
> resource has been assigned a new permanent URI and any future
> references to this resource ought to use one of the enclosed URIs. [...]
>
> **Note:** For historical reasons, a user agent MAY change the request
> method from `POST` to `GET` for the subsequent request.  If this
> behavior is undesired, the `307` (Temporary Redirect) status code
> can be used instead.

> [**6.4.3.  302 Found**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.3)
>
> The `302` (Found) status code indicates that the target resource
> resides temporarily under a different URI.  Since the redirection
> might be altered on occasion, the client ought to continue to use the
> effective request URI for future requests. [...]
>
> **Note:** For historical reasons, a user agent MAY change the request
> method from `POST` to `GET` for the subsequent request.  If this
> behavior is undesired, the `307` (Temporary Redirect) status code
> can be used instead.

> [**6.4.7.  307 Temporary Redirect**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.7)
>
> The `307` (Temporary Redirect) status code indicates that the target
> resource resides temporarily under a different URI and the user agent
> MUST NOT change the request method if it performs an automatic
> redirection to that URI.  Since the redirection can change over time,
> the client ought to continue using the original effective request URI
> for future requests. [...]
>
> **Note:** This status code is similar to `302` (Found), except that it
> does not allow changing the request method from `POST` to `GET`.  This
> specification defines no equivalent counterpart for `301` (Moved
> Permanently) ([RFC 7238](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7238), however, defines the status code `308`
> (Permanent Redirect) for this purpose).

### Changing the request method from `POST` to `GET`

The "historical reasons" in which a user agent may change a request from `POST` to `GET` is explained in an [Eric Lawrence](https://textslashplain.com/about/)'s [post from the IEInternals blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20190109001229/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2011/08/19/http-methods-and-redirect-status-codes/), dated from 19 August 2011.

The post quotes the definition of the status code `301` from the obsolete [RFC 1945](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1945.txt), published in May 1996, which defined the HTTP/1.0. The key part from that quote is:

> **Note:** When automatically redirecting a `POST` request after receiving a `301` status code, some existing user agents will erroneously change it into a `GET` request.

Then the author continues:

> [...] those “user agents” referred to in this remark included the popular browsers of the day, including Netscape Navigator and Internet Explorer. Arguably, this behavior is exactly what most websites wanted — after a successful `POST`, send the user to a different URL to show them something else. However, the `POST`-converted-to-`GET` behavior isn’t what the authors of HTTP had intended.

### The need for `308`

The [RFC 7238](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7238) has been created to define the [`308`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7538) (Permanent Redirect) status code, that is similar to [`301`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.2) (Moved Permanently) but does not allows the request method to be changed from `POST` to `GET`.

The [`308`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7538) status code is now defined by the [RFC 7538](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7538) (that obsoleted the [RFC 7238](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7238)).

> [**3.  308 Permanent Redirect**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7538)
>
> The `308` (Permanent Redirect) status code indicates that the target
> resource has been assigned a new permanent URI and any future
> references to this resource ought to use one of the enclosed URIs.
> Clients with link editing capabilities ought to automatically re-link
> references to the effective request URI to
> one or more of the new references sent by the server, where possible. [...]
>
> **Note:** This status code is similar to `301` (Moved Permanently),
> except that it does not allow changing the request method from
> `POST` to `GET`.

So we have the following:

```
                                                             +-----------+-----------+
                                                             | Permanent | Temporary |
+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+
| Allows changing the request method from POST to GET        | 301       | 302       |
+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+
| Doesn't allow changing the request method from POST to GET | 308       | 307       |
+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

### Choosing the most suitable status code

[Michael Kropat](https://stackoverflow.com/u/27581) put together a [set of decision charts](https://www.codetinkerer.com/2015/12/04/choosing-an-http-status-code.html) that helps to determine the best status code for each situation. See the following for `2xx` and `3xx` status codes:

[image: Picking a 2xx or 3xx status code]

Comment: Given that the question was specifically about the destinction between 301 and 308, could you give some more explanation on: _"does not allows the request method to be changed from `POST` to `GET`"_? Would it mean dat a posted form cannot be processed, but a fresh new form could be serverd and then be posted on a next request?

Comment: This draft specification (https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-hunt-http-rest-redirect-00.html) suggests that ReSTful services should use 308 even for GETs.
"HTTP redirection codes 301-306 SHOULD NOT be used unless the service provider is aware the client is in fact a user-agent."
However this is only a draft. I'm not sure if/when it will be accepted.

Comment: This post, [the-definitive-guide-to-get-vs-post](https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/the-definitive-guide-to-get-vs-post), clarifies why allowing a `POST` (safe) request to be *changed* into a to `GET` (unsafe in that data is passed by adding it to the url - and urls can be saved - including passwords) request can be a security issue, and generally should be avoided, unless you *know* it to be safe to change. These days it seems that it's generally supported and preferred to use 307, 308 over 301, 302. But you should verify.

Comment: Mnemonic `308` is like a sideways infinity, so Permanent redirect, and also never change the request Method - it is also a permanent, fixed request type. Then ,`307` is `1` step below - permanent/keep request Method (Get/Post), but redirect to a temp location: 7 - looks like "left turn" or temp detour, and 7 is also similar looking to k, so "keep" the request method.

Comment: You forgot to mention [Resume Incomplete](https://web.archive.org/web/20151013212135/http://code.google.com/p/gears/wiki/ResumableHttpRequestsProposal#Status_Code:_308_Resume_Incomplete).

Comment: @Knu That's not a [standard status code for HTTP](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml), at least not with that meaning: `308` has been standardised as _Permanent Redirect_.

Comment: @cassiomolin What does "historical reasons" mean here in _"For historical reasons, a user agent MAY change the request method from POST to GET for the subsequent request. If this behavior is undesired, the 307 (Temporary Redirect) status code can be used instead."_

Comment: @yogeshputtaswamy I think old HTTP RFCs will give you the context. See [this](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.html#section-10.3.3), [this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2068.html#section-10.3.3), and [this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945.html#page-35).

Comment: @yogeshputtaswamy By the way, I need to update my answer, as the RFCs 7130-35 have been obsoleted by a new set of RFCs: 9110-12.

Comment: @cassiomolin ... Didn't get what is the meaning of 'For historical reasons, a user agent MAY change the request method from POST to GET for the subsequent request.' in RFC Document. What does this 'historical reasons' mean?

Comment: @yogeshputtaswamy This [post](https://web.archive.org/web/20190109001229/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2011/08/19/http-methods-and-redirect-status-codes/) from the IEInternals blog dated 19 August 2011 should give you a good context on this.

Comment: @yogeshputtaswamy I updated my answer with these details.

Comment: For completeness it would make sense to mention the status `303 See Other`, which explicitly requires the request to be changed to `GET`, for those cases where the request was processed and then the next page to display should be fetched from other URL (it is on the diagram, but not described in the text).

Answer (score 2):

Mentioning below common observed client behavior when redirecting using 3xx status codes. Its best to test these scenarios with your HTTP client as it may not follow the same path as mentioned below.

**301**

- HTTP Method will be changed to GET. Not just POST but also DELETE, PUT, PATCH etc. (except for HEAD).
- While redirecting, most headers will be retained but certain sensitive headers like Authorization will be removed.
- Same domain, different scheme redirects (eg: http to https redirect) will retain sensitive headers as well.
- Body may or may not be removed. Since method is changed to GET, this will not matter in most cases.
- Indicates that search engines may update their links to the resource.

**302**

- Same as 301 but for temporary redirection. A browser redirects to this page but search engines don't update their links to the resource.

**308**

- HTTP Method will not change.
- Most headers will be retained but certain sensitive headers like Authorization will be removed. (exception with same domain redirects)
- Body will be retained.
- Search engines may update their links to the resource.

**307**

- Same as 308 but for temporary redirection. A browser redirects to this page but search engines don't update their links to the resource.

**303**

- This is useful when you want to give an answer to a PUT or POST method that is not the uploaded resources, but a confirmation message (like "You successfully uploaded XYZ") using a GET redirection. The result of the original HTTP request can be found at a different URL which can be separately identified, bookmarked, and cached, independent of the original request. Also, refresh of the result page doesn't re-trigger the POST/PUT operation. Some apps use 302 Found HTTP response for this purpose.
- All HTTP Method's except HEAD will be changed to GET.
- While redirecting, most headers will be retained but certain sensitive headers like Authorization will be removed. (exception with same domain redirects)

**300**

- Multiple choices redirect status response code indicates that the request has more than one possible response and the client should choose one of them.

Answer (score 0):

in short, the difference is when POST request (e.g carrying form data) hits a 301 moved permanently, user has to fill the form again(because browser converts the method to GET). But if the POST request hits 308 permanent redirect user is not required to fill the form again