# Moved POST request permanently

Tags: http, retrofit

Our mobile application uses a POST request to check its status. We need to migrate this service to new location. We have released new version of the mobile application using new endpoint. And I planned to release update of the service that redirects the client to new location.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/url", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
public void performHandShake(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
    response.setHeader("Location", service.getNewUrl());
}
```

I am testing this service with Postman and current Android implementation and they both fail on HTTP error 405 - method not allowed. It seems that they both redirect to GET instead of requested POST. Is there any proper way to redirect the POST request? I do not want to implement a proxy to the new endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`308`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7538) instead of [`301`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.2) if you don't want the have the request method changed from `POST` to `GET`:

> [**6.4.2.  301 Moved Permanently**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.2)
>
> The `301` (Moved Permanently) status code indicates that the target
> resource has been assigned a new permanent URI and any future
> references to this resource ought to use one of the enclosed URIs. [...]
>
> **Note:** For historical reasons, a user agent MAY change the request
> method from `POST` to `GET` for the subsequent request.  If this
> behavior is undesired, the `307` (Temporary Redirect) status code
> can be used instead.

> [**3.  308 Permanent Redirect**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7538)
>
> The `308` (Permanent Redirect) status code indicates that the target
> resource has been assigned a new permanent URI and any future
> references to this resource ought to use one of the enclosed URIs.
> Clients with link editing capabilities ought to automatically re-link
> references to the effective request URI to
> one or more of the new references sent by the server, where possible. [...]
>
> **Note:** This status code is similar to `301` (Moved Permanently),
> except that it does not allow changing the request method from
> `POST` to `GET`.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42138726/1426227) for more details.

Comment: Nice. Unfortunatelly currently used library (com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0) does not support this code. And because I need a solution for existing customers that do not upgrade I cannot change the library.

Comment: @LeosLiterak Well, you could try [`307` (Temporary Redirect)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.4.7).