# proper status code for redirecting an invalid route

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, http-status-codes

I have the following routes set up:

```js
/business //look for a business
/business/biz/:id //look at a specific business
```

What I did is that if someone goes to `/business/biz` it redirects to `/business`.
My question is what status code I should use for that?
I don't think it's `301` or `302` because it's not a permanent move, and it's also not temporary, it's just a page that doesn't exist with a consistent redirect to a specific page.

```js
//get /business/biz page
router.get("/biz", (req, res) => {
  res.redirect("/business");
});
```

I looked at different questions here on Stack Overflow but didn't find a case that matches mine.

Comment: Are you changing the http method too?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon what do you mean? it's a normal `res.redirect` method

Comment: I see `biz/id`, where are the `id` in the redirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect `/business/biz` on `/business` you should return a `308 Permanent Redirect`.
This is a quote from Wikipedia about status 308 :

> The request and all future requests should be repeated using another URI. 307 and 308 parallel the behaviors of 302 and 301, **but do not allow the HTTP method to change**. So, for example, submitting a form to a permanently redirected resource may continue smoothly

You should also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42138726/11825162) explaining differences between `301`, `308`, `302`, `307` and is well written.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use the `301` code only as a response for `GET` or `HEAD` methods and to use the `308` Permanent Redirect for `POST` methods instead.

Check the full article [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/301)