# Hiding .php in URL breaks contact form

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a fully working site with a number of various contact forms.

I hid the .php at the end of each pages name in the URL using the .htaccess file but when I do this the contact form breaks.  Is there another way of hiding these suffixes?

Many thanks

Comment: Show your .htaccess by editing question. Is your form using `POST` method?

Comment: Yeah using POST.  Below is the htaccess file:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]

Comment: Please "edit your question" (as anubhava suggested) to add the contents of your `.htaccess` file. Posting unformatted code (especially regex) in a comment can omit special characters from display and render the code sample useless.

Comment: Also, how is the "contact form" being called, what's the end-point?

Answer (score 2):

You should skip `POST` requests from redirect rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Modern browsers support [HTTP status code 308](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42136829/whats-the-difference-between-http-301-and-308-status-codes) that doesn't change a `POST` request to `GET`, so you may use first rule as:

```sh
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=308,NE,L]
```