# Unsupported media type \"application/x-www-form-urlencoded\" in request

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, postman

I am using ViewSets for Profile model but if I send request in Postman I am getting following error.

`Unsupported media type \"application/x-www-form-urlencoded\" in request`

But I do not have a idea What I am doing wrong.

```
class ProfileView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)
    permission_classes = (IsOwnerOrAdmin,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(ProfileView, self).get_queryset().filter(user=self.request.user)

    def get_object(self):
        qs = Profile.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).first()
        return qs

    def put(self, request):
        file = request.data['file']
        return Response(status=204)
```

I have configured in `settings.py` file as well. But I cannot work this out. Any help would be appericated. Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to pass `Content-Type` parameter of your request to `application/json`.[This might be similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18088159/4067931)

Comment: If I do this error changes to `"detail": "Unsupported media type \"application/json\" in request."`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specified the `MultiPartParser` as parser so you need to do a proper multipart query. You can do it by [selecting "form-data" option in Postman](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/requests/#form-data):

> `multipart/form-data` is the default encoding a web form uses to transfer data. This simulates filling a form on a website, and submitting it. The form-data editor lets you set key-value pairs (using the data editor for your data.) It also lets you specify the content type for each part of a multi-part form request individually. You can attach files to a key as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't upload any image, then just change the parser class to FormParser

```
from rest_framework.parsers import FormParser

class ProfileView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    parser_classes = (FormPartParser,)
    permission_classes = (IsOwnerOrAdmin,)
```