# Open URL "silently" in python or similar

Tags: python, batch-file

Is there anyway to open a URL in Python without opening a tab in a browser?

I have a preconstructed URL which I would like to run when the computer is idle e.g. http://foo.com/bar

I've been able to use the `start` and `webbrowser` methods but these open a new tab in my browser.

*F.Y.I.* The URL returns a blank page with nothing more than the word `OK` which I don't need.

Could anyone suggest any other way like via a batch or any other program that could do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [urllib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib) (Python 2.x):

```
import urllib
urllib.urlopen('http://foo.com/bar')
```

(Python 3.x)

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlopen('http://foo.com/bar')
```

Comment: @sudo_O, Sorry, I don't understand what do you mean. Do you mean I should recommend to use urllib2 rather than urllib?

Comment: Yes but as in @SamStudio8 request is an even better choice. Related quesiton http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018026/should-i-use-urllib-or-urllib2-or-requests

Answer (score 6):

You could also check out the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module.
If you don't need the actual content you could just check the HTTP status code?

```
import requests
result = requests.get('http://foo.com/bar')

if(result.status_code == 200): print("OK")
```

Comment: I'd agree with using requests over urllib(2); it's billed as 'http for humans' and generally follows a philosophy of being easy to use and read.

Comment: I should have mentioned you'd need to install it first, you can run `pip install requests` on your terminal or alternatively follow the instructions [on the website](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install.html#get-the-code) to install it from the source.

Answer (score 0):

**First Install "requests"**

Run in command prompt :

```
pip install requests
```

then run this code :

```
username ='abcd'
password='password'
url = 'www.example.com/data/con'
r=requests.get(url)
page=r.content
print(page)
```