# Which urllib I should choose?

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib, urllib3

as we know, python has two built-in url lib:

- `urllib`
- `urllib2`

and a third-party lib:

- `urllib3`

if my requirement is only to request a API by GET method, assume it return a JSON string.
which lib I should use? do they have some duplicated functions?
if the `urllib` can implement my require, but after if my requirements get more and more complicated, the `urllib` can not fit my function, I should import another lib at that time, but I really want to import only one lib, because I think import all of them can make me confused, I think the method between them are totally different.

so now I am confused which lib I should use, I prefer `urllib3`, I think it can fit my requirement all time, how do you think?

Comment: python [requests](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is the best you can get for simple http requests

Comment: maybe this question has relation with:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018026/should-i-use-urllib-or-urllib2-or-requests

Comment: As the author of urllib3, I highly suggest going with either requests (which is built on top of urllib3) or straight-up urllib3. Requests has a higher-level friendlier interface that many people like, that's up to you. Thanks to urllib3, you get a lot of things for free like connection reusing and more. Full list here: https://github.com/shazow/urllib3#highlights

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Alexander says in the comments, use `requests`. That's all you need.

Comment: yes, thanks. I read *requests* docs, it base on _urllib3_, I think I can use it to finish almost my jobs

Answer (score 4):

I don't really know what you want to do, but you should try with [`requests`](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It's simple and intuitive.

Comment: less *import*, consistent style methods

Answer (score 1):

Personally I avoid to use third-party library when possible, so I can reduce the dependencies' list and improve portability.
urllib and urllib2 are not mutually exclusive and are often mixed in the same project.