# urllib2 Error 403: Forbidden

Tags: python, urllib2

I have posted to this site and received really helpful guidance, i return with another question.

Where have i gone wrong here, I was prettty sure this is what is required to access information from various sites. In this case, the CME Group.

```
   import urllib2

url = "http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/natural-gas/natural-gas.html"
request= urllib2.Request(url)
handle = urllib2.urlopen(request)
content = handle.read()
splitted_page = content.split("<span class=\"cmeSubHeading\">", 1);
splitted_page = splitted_page[1].split("</span>", 1)
print splitted_page[0]
```

Error reads,

```
HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Thank you greatly in advance.

Comment: You need to simulate the user agent so server doesnot think that you are a 'bad' guy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem is that they block everyone who doesn't have a user-agent

```
import urllib2

request = urllib2.Request("http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/natural-gas/natural-gas.html", None, {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
content = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
splitted_page = content.split("<span class=\"cmeSubHeading\">", 1);
splitted_page = splitted_page[1].split("</span>", 1)
print splitted_page[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have to do GET requests I reccomend you the Requests python package. You can read its advantages in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018026/should-i-use-urllib-or-urllib2-or-requests).

However, if you're getting a 403 message maybe you're trying to access some restricted data ([Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403)).