# How can I decode python-requests URL?

Tags: python, python-requests

I know if I want to send an HTTP request, I can form it as a dictionary before sending it:

```
payload = dict(
    username="something",
    password="something_else"
)

r = requests.get('http://example.com', params=payload)
```

Does it do the opposite as well? If my request happens to redirect me to another URL, I can see where I was redirected with:

```
print r.url
```

But if that URL happens to be something like:

```
http://example.com/somepage.htm?varone=test&vartwo=3451&varthree=something
```

and I happen to want to pull out the vartwo from that URL (the string 3451), does the requests module provide any easy way to do this just by specifying that I want the value of "vartwo"? Another dictionary, or mapping object of some sort perhaps? Or is my only option to use urllib.unquote to decode the url, and parse it as a string?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28328890/python-requests-extract-url-parameters-from-a-string

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113090/best-way-to-parse-a-url-query-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [urlparse module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) (Python 2.x; in Python 3.x, it was renamed to [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html)).

```
from urlparse import urlparse

url = 'http://www.gurlge.com:80/path/file.html;params?a=1#fragment'
o = urlparse(url)

print o.params
```