# How can I get a random number in Rust 1.0?

Tags: random, rust

I tried

```
use std::rand::{task_rng, Rng};

fn main() {
    // a number from [-40.0, 13000.0)
    let num: f64 = task_rng().gen_range(-40.0, 1.3e4);
    println!("{}", num);
}
```

but this gives

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `std::rand::task_rng`
 --> rand.rs:1:17
  |
1 | use std::rand::{task_rng, Rng};
  |                 ^^^^^^^^ no `task_rng` in `rand`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `std::rand::Rng`
 --> rand.rs:1:27
  |
1 | use std::rand::{task_rng, Rng};
  |                           ^^^ no `Rng` in `rand`

error[E0603]: module `rand` is private
 --> rand.rs:1:17
  |
1 | use std::rand::{task_rng, Rng};
  |                 ^^^^^^^^

error[E0603]: module `rand` is private
 --> rand.rs:1:27
  |
1 | use std::rand::{task_rng, Rng};
  |                           ^^^
```

and I tried

```
extern crate rand;
use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    if rng.gen() {
        // random bool
        println!("i32: {}, u32: {}", rng.gen::<i32>(), rng.gen::<u32>())
    }
    let tuple = rand::random::<(f64, char)>();
    println!("{:?}", tuple)
}
```

and got

```
error[E0425]: cannot find function `thread_rng` in module `rand`
 --> rand.rs:5:29
  |
5 |         let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
  |                             ^^^^^^^^^^ not found in `rand`
  |
help: possible candidate is found in another module, you can import it into scope
  |     use std::__rand::thread_rng;

error[E0425]: cannot find function `random` in module `rand`
  --> rand.rs:10:27
   |
10 |         let tuple = rand::random::<(f64, char)>();
   |                           ^^^^^^ not found in `rand`

error: use of unstable library feature 'rand': use `rand` from crates.io (see issue #27703)
 --> rand.rs:1:5
  |
1 |     extern crate rand;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: use of unstable library feature 'rand': use `rand` from crates.io (see issue #27703)
 --> rand.rs:2:9
  |
2 |     use rand::Rng;
  |         ^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Note that this is a beginners question. This is (after a "Hello World") the second thing I've tried.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In the far past, the `rand` crate  was part of the standard library but has long since been [extracted to a crate](https://crates.io/crates/rand). This crate should be the one you use:

Specify a **Cargo.toml**:

```
[package]
name = "stackoverflow"
version = "0.0.1"
authors = ["A. Developer <developer@example.com>"]

[dependencies]
rand = "0.7.0" # Or a newer version
```

Then your example code works:

```
use rand::Rng; // 0.7.2

fn main() {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    if rng.gen() { // random bool
        println!("i32: {}, u32: {}", rng.gen::<i32>(), rng.gen::<u32>())
    }
    let tuple = rand::random::<(f64, char)>();
    println!("{:?}", tuple)
}
```

With the output:

```
$ cargo run
     Running `target/debug/so`
i32: 1819776837, u32: 3293137459
(0.6052759716514547, '\u{69a69}')

$ cargo run
     Running `target/debug/so`
(0.23882541338214436, '\u{10deee}')
```

> Why were these useful functions removed from stdlib?

Rust has a philosophy of placing as much as possible into crates instead of the standard library. This allows each piece of code to grow and evolve at a different rate than the standard library and also allows the code to *stop being used* without forcing it to be maintained forever.

A common example is the [sequence of HTTP libraries in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018026/what-are-the-differences-between-the-urllib-urllib2-and-requests-module). There are multiple packages that all do the same thing in different ways and the Python maintainers have to keep **all** of them to provide backwards compatibility.

Crates allow this particular outcome to be avoided. If a crate truly stabilizes for a long time, I'm sure it could be re-added to the standard library.

Comment: Can you please explain why these useful functions are removed from stdlib ?