# How to crawl the description for sfglobe using python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use Python and Beautifulsoup to get this page from sfglobe website: http://sfglobe.com/2015/04/28/stirring-pictures-from-the-riots-in-baltimore.
This is the code:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

url = 'http://sfglobe.com/2015/04/28/stirring-pictures-from-the-riots-in-baltimore' 
req = urllib2.urlopen(url) 
html = req.read() 
soup = BeautifulSoup(html) 
desc = soup.find('span', class_='articletext intro')
```

Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: My code is in the following way:
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://sfglobe.com/2015/04/28/stirring-pictures-from-the-riots-in-baltimore'

req = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = req.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

desc = soup.find('span', class_='articletext intro')

Comment: Edit your question and add the code there, to be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

From the question title, I assuming that the only thing you want is the description of the article, which can be found in the `<meta>` tag within the HTML `<head>`.

You were on the right track, but I'm not exactly sure why you did:

```
desc = soup.find('span', class_='articletext intro')
```

Regardless, I came up with something using `requests` (see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018026/should-i-use-urllib-or-urllib2-or-requests](http://this%20SO%20post)) rather than `urllib2`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://sfglobe.com/2015/04/28/stirring-pictures-from-the-riots-in-baltim\
ore'
req = requests.get(url)
html = req.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

tag = soup.find(attrs={'name':'description'}) # find meta tag w/ description
desc = tag['value'] # get value of attribute 'value'

print desc
```

If that isn't what you are looking for, please clarify so I can try and help you more.

**EDIT: after some clarification, I pieced together why you were originally using** `desc = soup.find('span', class_='articletext intro')`.

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString

url = 'http://sfglobe.com/2015/04/28/stirring-pictures-from-the-riots-in-baltimore'
req = requests.get(url)
html = req.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

body = soup.find('span', class_='articletext intro')

# remove script tags
[s.extract() for s in body('script')]

text = ""

# iterate through non-script elements in the content body
for stuff in body.select('*'):
    # get contents of tags, .contents returns a list
    content = stuff.contents
    # check if the list has the text content a.k.a. isn't empty AND is a NavigableString, not a tag
    if len(content) == 1 and isinstance(content[0], NavigableString):
        text += content[0]

print text
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I tried to use your method, while it just returns the first paragraph of the description. How can I get the full description? Thanks  a lot.

Comment: I think I get what you were trying to do with `desc = soup.find('span', class_='articletext intro')` now. Updating my answer.

Comment: Hi, Bryce: Thank you so much for your help. However, for your method,  the body is 'Nonetype' on my side (body = soup.find('span', class_='articletext intro')). Can you get some results? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I get the proper output, which is a paragraph consisting of the text of the article body. Do you have `requests` installed? Can you successfully open that link in your browser?

Comment: All right, I think my problem is " body = soup.find('span', class_='articletext intro')" returns None when I ran on my side.  I have installed the requests lib, and I can open the link successfully, It is so wired.

Comment: Can you make sure that you are not missing any lines of code, and if that doesn't work, you can share your code here so that I can take a look.