# Python http get - cannot replicate a curl request with headers

Tags: python, curl, http-headers, urllib2, http-get

I have the following curl command:

```
curl -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -X GET http://example.com/en/number/111555000
```

Unfortunately I was not able to replicate it...
I tried with:

```
   url = http://example.com/en/number/111555000
   headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0', 'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', 'Connection':'keep-alive',}
   req = urllib2.Request(url, None, headers)
   resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
   print resp.read()
```

but the server recognized some how that the request is "fake" and forwards me to google (reply from server is: `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently`). With curl instead I receive the original page.

Any ideas or suggestions?
Thank you
dk

EDIT: some additional infos:

```
$ nc example.com 80 
GET /en/number/111555000 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Fri, 29 May 2015 18:51:05 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.24
Location: http://www.google.de
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html


$ nc example.com 80 
GET /en/number/111555000 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 29 May 2015 18:57:56 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.24
Set-Cookie: session=a%3A4%3A%7Bs...
Set-Cookie: session=a%3A4%3A%7Bs...
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=200
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

1c6f8
<!DOCTYPE html>
[...]
```

with curl:

```
$curl -X GET http://example.com/en/number/111555000
$

$ curl -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -X GET http://example.com/en/number/111555000
<!DOCTYPE html>
[...]
```

Comment: What happens if you use curl without headers? Are you sure the server accepts headers like that?

Comment: Nothing happens, no answer:
`$ curl -X GET http://example.com/en/number/111555000`
`$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can get it to work with the requests library. Which is [probably better to use.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018026/should-i-use-urllib-or-urllib2-or-requests)

```
import requests
url = "http://example.com/en/number/111555000"
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0', 'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', 'Connection':'keep-alive',}
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
req.text
```

[here is the requests library documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org)

Hope it helps.