# Difference between requests.get() and urrlib.request.urlopen() python

Tags: python

When I use:

```
import requests
r = requests.get("https://example.com")
```

I get the following exception:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)
```

However, If i use following code:

```
url = "https://www.example.com"
request = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
```

It gives me the correct response[200] code. Why is it so? What is the difference between these two methods and which one should be preferred?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the former one:
I will add the source of why it's better.
Anyways you need to set `verify` as `False` to prevent requests from verifying SSL certificates for HTTPS requests:

```
import requests
r = requests.get("https://example.com", verify=False)
```

Edit:

> Difference between requests.get() and urllib.request.urlopen() python

[What are the differences between the urllib, urllib2, and requests module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018026/what-are-the-differences-between-the-urllib-urllib2-and-requests-module)

Comment: So correct me if i am wrong,request.get() [with default verify=true] will try to verify the certificate and urllib.request.urlopen() does not do that.

Comment: it's done explicity by using https connection https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPSConnection

Comment: Thanks, i got it now. Its always better to use request.get/post so that it will perform ssl verification for you. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because example.com does not have a valid certificate. So requests warns you that the https connection won't be trusted. If you trust the server then you should do what wolframalpha suggested.