# Login to a website using python and urllib2

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping

I need to login into the following website http://mediaweather.meteogroup.co.uk/ I attempted to do this using python with the following code but it doesn't appear to login any help would be appreciated :)

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib

username = ''
password = ''

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'username' : username, 'password' : password})
opener.open('http://mediaweather.meteogroup.co.uk/login', login_data)
resp = opener.open('http://mediaweather.meteogroup.co.uk/observations/table/6040?country_id=6040&d=01&m=07&y=2016&h=11&i=00&sort=landstat_name_wmo&order=asc')
print resp.read()
```

Comment: You should take a look at [mechanize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/)

Comment: Use `requests` for Web request,  why?  - Here -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018026/what-are-the-differences-between-the-urllib-urllib2-and-requests-module

Comment: You can try the selenium library as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) to post the form data, the following shows you how:

```
# post url for logon
url = "http://mediaweather.meteogroup.co.uk/login/process"

data = {"txtusername": "username",
        "txtpassword": "pass"}

with requests.Session() as s:
        # login
        s.post(url, data=data)
        # get page you want
        html = s.get('http://mediaweather.meteogroup.co.uk/observations/table/6040?country_id=6040&d=01&m=07&y=2016&h=11&i=00&sort=landstat_name_wmo&order=asc).content
```