# How to get googles "fast answer box" text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to get googles "fast answer box" text. What I mean by "fast answer box" should be clear on visiting the screenshot:[image]

This Box is shown by google if you enter a search and google knows the answer. So you don't need to open one of the links shown below. The box is shown if you enter following query:

https://google.de/search?q=definition%20calcium

Now I want to read this text via python script. I write a method which uses requests and beautiful soup to achieve this:

```
def execute(self):
    response = requests.get(url='https://google.de/search?q=definition%20calcium', proxies=self._proxy)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    return soup.find_all("ol", class_="lr_dct_sf_sens")
```

The Method always returns [], which means an empty list. But if I use chrome console I can find exactly this term:

[image]

So I can't understand why this can't be found. For testing I write the whole content from `requests.get` into a file with this:

```
file = open('C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\test.txt', 'w')
file.write(response.text)
file.close()
```

Tried to search the file with notepad but I can't the search pattern there as well. Not sure if `response.text` cuts some details.

Is someone out there, who can explain this to me? How can I get this text?

Comment: Do you have JavaScript enabled in Chrome? It may be updating the page once the html has loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you watch closely on your Network requests when loading that page you'll see that google fires up another link which contains your data.

Please try to access this in your browser:

`https://www.google.com/search?q=definition:+calcium&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.&cad=b&fp=1&biw=1920&bih=984&dpr=1&tch=1&ech=1&psi=1489578048971.3`

It'll download a file on which your fastbox data is available. You can search in that file for `the chemical element of atomic number` to verify this.

You'll have to clean the file and scrape the data that you want.

Comment: Great feedback, any suggestions on how to parse that very response? Should I look for this `(cdiv style\\x3d\\x22display:inline\\x22 data-dobid\\x3d\\x22dfn\\x22\\x3e\\x3cspan\\x3ethe chemical element of atomic number 20, a soft gray metal.\\x3c\/span\\x3e\\x3c\/div\\)`

Comment: I think this is what I have to filter by `<div style="display:inline" data-dobid="dfn"><span>`

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the easiest way is to grab CSS selectors of this text by using the [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension in combination with `select()` or `select_one()` `beautifulsoup` [methods](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors).

Also, the problem could be is that you don't specify a `user-agent`. `User-agent` used to fake a real user visit, so Google (or other website) don't block a request.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.de/search?q=definition%20calcium', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

syllables = soup.select_one('.frCXef span').text
phonetic = soup.select_one('.g30o5d span span').text
noun = soup.select_one('.h3TRxf span').text
print(f'{syllables}\n{phonetic}\n{noun}')

# Output:
'''
cal·ci·um
ˈkalsēəm
the chemical element of atomic number 20, a soft gray metal.
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can do the same thing using [Google Direct Answer Box API](https://serpapi.com/direct-answer-box-api) from SerpApi, except you don't have to figure out how to grab certain HTML elements. It's a paid API with a free trial of 5,000 searches.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "definition calcium",
  "google_domain": "google.com",
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

syllables = results['answer_box']['syllables']
phonetic = results['answer_box']['phonetic']
noun = results['answer_box']['definitions'][0] # specifying index since the output is an array
print(f'{syllables}\n{phonetic}\n{noun}')

# Output:
'''
cal·ci·um
ˈkalsēəm
the chemical element of atomic number 20, a soft gray metal.
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.

Answer (score -1):

SerpApi fully support dictionary results that are inside Google direct answer boxes. For example:

```
$ curl https://serpapi.com/search.json?q=definition%20calcium&google_domain=google.de
...
  "answer_box": {
    "type": "dictionary_results",
    "syllables": "cal·ci·um",
    "phonetic": "/ˈkalsēəm/",
    "word_type": "noun",
    "definitions": [
      "the chemical element of atomic number 20, a soft gray metal."
    ]
  },
...
```

Some documentation for dictionary results are here: https://serpapi.com/direct-answer-box-api