# when I use urllib2 to crawl a wibsite,but without labels ,such as html,body

Tags: python, urllib2, label

```
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.bilibili.com/video/av1669338'

user_agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"

headers={"User-Agent":user_agent}

request=urllib2.Request(url,headers=headers)

response=urllib2.urlopen(request)

text = response.read()

text[:100]
```

'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\xcd}ys\x1bG\xb2\xe7\xdfV\xc4|\x87\x1exhRk\x81\xb8\x08\x10\x90E\xfa\x89\xb2f\x9f\xe3\xd9\xcf\x9e\x1dyb7\xec\tD\x03h\x90\x90p\t\x07)yf"D\xf9I&EI\xd4}\x91\xb6.\xeb\xb0e\x93\x94%Y\xbc$E\xccW\x194\x00\xfe\xe5\xaf\xf0~Y\xd5\xd5\xa8\xeeF\x83\xa7'

Comment: Looks like that URL is serving (binary) video content, not HTML.  What were you expecting?

Comment: I want to crawl the label (<meta name="keywords" content="哔哩哔哩,Bilibili,B站,弹幕,娱乐,综艺,暴走漫画,暴走漫画,娱乐,真正的粉丝,综艺,暴走出品,关注青少年儿童,红鼻子节,求尼玛老公抱,暴走大事件第五季," />),what the content values,but it's not have this label, even not have html label,I don't know what happened

Comment: The response is gzip encoded see `1F 8B` or `'\x1f\x8b` is the magic number / header definition of gzip see : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures or https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1952#section-2.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import bs4, requests
res = requests.get("http://www.bilibili.com/video/av1669338")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.content, "lxml")
result = soup.find("meta", attrs = {"name":"keywords"}).get("content")
print result
```

Comment: Thank You！Could you tell me why use bs4 can solve this problem?

Comment: @fan the thing is that here we use `requests` instead of `urllib2`, and then we pass the content of the response to bs4 to find the element very easily. For the difference of  `requests` and `urllib2`, you could refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018026/what-are-the-differences-between-the-urllib-urllib2-and-requests-module

Comment: Thanks ! It's very helpful for me .Best Wishes

Answer (score 1):

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def data():
    url = 'http://www.bilibili.com/video/av1669338'
    user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
    headers = {"User-Agent": user_agent}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

```
data = response.content
_html = BeautifulSoup(data)
_meta = _html.head.select('meta[name=keywords]')
print _meta[0]['content']
```