# Python download multiple files from links on pages

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, urllib

I'm trying to download all the [PGN](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Portable_Game_Notation)s from this [site](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chesscollection?cid=1014492).

I think I have to use `urlopen` to open each url and then use `urlretrieve` to download each pgn by accessing it from the download button near the bottom of each game. Do I have to create a new `BeautifulSoup` object for each game? I'm also unsure of how `urlretrieve` works.

```
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen, urlretrieve, quote
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chesscollection?cid=1014492'
u = urlopen(url)
html = u.read().decode('utf-8')

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    urlopen('http://chessgames.com'+link.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no short answer to your question. I will show you a complete solution and comment this code.

First, import necessary modules:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
```

Next, get index page and create `BeautifulSoup` object:

```
req = requests.get("http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chesscollection?cid=1014492")
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")
```

I strongly advice to use `lxml` parser, not common `html.parser`
After that, you should prepare game's links list:

```
pages = soup.findAll('a', href=re.compile('.*chessgame\?.*'))
```

You can do it by searching links containing 'chessgame' word in it.
Now, you should prepare function which will download files for you:

```
def download_file(url):
    path = url.split('/')[-1].split('?')[0]
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        with open(path, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r:
                f.write(chunk)
```

And final magic is to repeat all previous steps preparing links for file downloader:

```
host = 'http://www.chessgames.com'
for page in pages:
    url = host + page.get('href')
    req = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")
    file_link = soup.find('a',text=re.compile('.*download.*'))
    file_url = host + file_link.get('href')
    download_file(file_url)
```

(first you search links containing text 'download' in their description, then construct full url - concatenate hostname and path, and finally download file)

I hope you can use this code without correction!

Comment: Why should I use requests and not urllib by the way? Can you do the same thing with urllib?

Comment: Of course, you can use `urllib` as you did in your question. But using `requests` is a good practice. You can obtain additional information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018026/what-are-the-differences-between-the-urllib-urllib2-and-requests-module)

Comment: What do these 2 lines of code do?`req = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")`I understand that the first line makes a request but don't really understand what that means? And what does the .text method do in the BS constructor? I understand that it gets all the child strings but again am not sure what that means in this context.

Comment: `req = requests.get(url)` gives you an object of type `requests.models.Response`. It is a class, containing http response itself and a number of attributes and methods to deal with. One of the attributes is `text` which lets you obtain pure html code of the web page received. You should pass this html code to BeautifuSoup object's constructor as an argument (`soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")`) to get BeautifulSoup object - a class which methods let you search certain tags and others.

Answer (score 6):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46275616/6243352) is fantastic but the task is [embarrassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel); there's no need to retrieve these sub-pages and files one at a time. This answer shows how to speed things up.

The first step is to use [`requests.Session()`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#request-sessions) when sending multiple requests to a single host. Quoting [Advanced Usage: Session Objects](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) from the `requests` docs:

> The Session object allows you to persist certain parameters across requests. It also persists cookies across all requests made from the Session instance, and will use `urllib3`'s [connection pooling](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/index.html#module-urllib3.connectionpool). So if you're making several requests to the same host, the underlying TCP connection will be reused, which can result in a significant performance increase (see [HTTP persistent connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection)).

Next, asyncio, multiprocessing or multithreading are available to parallelize the workload. Each has tradeoffs respective to the task at hand and which you choose is likely best determined by benchmarking and profiling. [This page](https://realpython.com/python-concurrency/) offers great examples of all three.

For the purposes of this post, I'll show multithreading. The impact of the GIL shouldn't be too much of a bottleneck because the tasks are mostly IO-bound, consisting of babysitting requests on the air to wait for the response. When a thread is blocked on IO, it can yield to a thread parsing HTML or doing other CPU-bound work.

Here's the code:

```py
import os
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def download_pgn(task):
    session, host, page, destination_path = task
    response = session.get(host + page)
    response.raise_for_status()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
    game_url = host + soup.find("a", text="download").get("href")
    filename = re.search(r"\w+\.pgn", game_url).group()
    path = os.path.join(destination_path, filename)
    response = session.get(game_url, stream=True)
    response.raise_for_status()

    with open(path, "wb") as f:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            if chunk:
                f.write(chunk)

def main():
    host = "http://www.chessgames.com"
    url_to_scrape = host + "/perl/chesscollection?cid=1014492"
    destination_path = "pgns"
    max_workers = 8

    if not os.path.exists(destination_path):
        os.makedirs(destination_path)

    with requests.Session() as session:
        session.headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
        response = session.get(url_to_scrape)
        response.raise_for_status()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
        pages = soup.find_all("a", href=re.compile(r".*chessgame\?.*"))
        tasks = [
            (session, host, page.get("href"), destination_path) 
            for page in pages
        ]

        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers) as pool:
            pool.map(download_pgn, tasks)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I used [`response.iter_content`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.iter_content) here which is unnecessary on such tiny text files, but is a generalization so the code will handle larger files in a memory-friendly way.

Results from a rough benchmark (the first request is a bottleneck):

| max workers | session? | seconds |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | no | 126 |
| 1 | yes | 111 |
| 8 | no | 24 |
| 8 | yes | 22 |
| 32 | yes | 16 |