# How to download all files from webpage that correspond to a certain string in the title?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, download

I need to download all the files from this page :

https://www.dmo.gov.uk/publications/?offset=0&itemsPerPage=1000000&parentFilter=1433&childFilter=1433%7C1450&startMonth=1&startYear=2008&endMonth=6&endYear=2021

**that have "Auction of" on their titles.** This is the source for one of the files for example:

```
<a href="/media/17527/pr090621b.pdf" aria-label="Auction of £2,500 million  of 0 5/8% Treasury Gilt 2035, published 09 June 2021">Auction of £2,500 million  of 0 5/8% Treasury Gilt 2035</a>
```

I am trying to adapt some code I found [from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46264056/python-download-multiple-files-from-links-on-pages), but the pages are coming back empty:

```
import os
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def download_pgn(task):
    session, url, destination_path = task
    response = session.get(url)
    response.raise_for_status()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
    game_url = host + soup.find("a", text="download").get("href")
    filename = re.search(r"\w+\.pgn", game_url).group()
    path = os.path.join(destination_path, filename)
    response = session.get(game_url, stream=True)
    response.raise_for_status()

    with open(path, "wb") as f:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            if chunk:
                f.write(chunk)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    destination_path = "pgns"
    max_workers = 8

    if not os.path.exists(destination_path):
        os.makedirs(destination_path)
    
    with requests.Session() as session:
        response = session.get(url)
        response.raise_for_status()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
        pages = soup.find_all("a", href=re.compile(r".*Auction of\?.*"))
        tasks = [
            (session, host + page.get("href"), destination_path) 
            for page in pages
        ]

        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers) as pool:
            pool.map(download_pgn, tasks)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your regular expression syntax. The regex `r".*Auction of\?.*"` will only match titles with an actual `of?` in the title.

But the href= parameter will search against the URL in the link, so that won't help you much either. This will find the links with the matching titles:

```
links = soup.find_all("a", string=re.compile(r"Auction of\b"))
```

And this will extract their URLs so you can retrieve them:

```
[ file["href"] for file in links ]
```

Comment: so it's there no way to select for the title? since it's not in the href

Comment: Sure there is, edited the answer. (Also check https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all for the next time...)

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working for me:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
links = []
url = 'https://www.dmo.gov.uk/publications/?offset=0&itemsPerPage=1000000000&parentFilter=1433&childFilter=1433|1450&startMonth=1&startYear=2000&endMonth=6&endYear=2021'
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")
for a in soup.find_all("a",{"aria-label":re.compile(r"^Auction of\b")}, href=True):
    links.append(a['href'])

def download_file(url):
    path = url.split('/')[-1].split('?')[0]
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        with open(path, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r:
                f.write(chunk)

host = 'https://www.dmo.gov.uk/'

for link in links:
    url = host + link
    download_file(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `find_all()` method [accepts a function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function). You can create a `lambda` function to filter all for `a` tags that contain "Auction of":

```
for tag in soup.find_all(lambda t: t.name == "a" and "Auction of" in t):
    print(tag.text)
```

Or, you can use an [`[attribute*=value]`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_contain.asp):

```
# Find all `aria-label` attributes under an `a` that contain `Auction of`
for tag in soup.select("a[aria-label*='Auction of']"):
    print(tag.text)
```