# Retrieving anchor tags while creating a web crawler in python

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, pycharm, urllib

I am creating a web crawler and trying to run program in pycharm to retrieve anchor tags of a URL.But the output I am getting is just the very same URL which I have entered. Code is as below:

```
    import urllib.request,urllib.parse,urllib.error
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import ssl
    ctx=ssl.create_default_context()
    ctx.check_hostname=False
    ctx.verify_mode=ssl.CERT_NONE

    url=input("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Inc.")
    html=urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
    soup=BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    tags=soup("a")
    for tag in tags:
        print(tag.get("href",None))
```

One thing to notice here is that in urllib library only urllib.error is showing as used statement and both urllib.request and urllib.parse is showing as unused statement which I can't  understand why.

The output for this program is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Inc.

I am using python 3.5.1 and pycharm community edition.

Answer (score 0):

You really should use the `requests` package. It is extremely useful for crawling purposes. Check out [this user response about requests.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14804320/6454584)

Here is your code converted:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

request = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Inc.").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(request, "html.parser")

anchor = soup.find_all("a", href=True)
for a in anchor:
    print (a["href"])
```