# Handling window.alert during BeautifulSoup sitescrape

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a page that upon load, fires up a JS `window.alert`

The script cannot proceed while this box is present as it stops the rest of the page loading.

How to stop the alert appearing?

I am grabbing the page using `requests` library.

Comment: BeautifulSoup doesn't execute any Javascript -- it just parses the html you give it. What are you using for the request? `urllib.request` won't do this either, you'd have to use something like `selenium`

Comment: Updated - using `requests` library

Comment: Even `requests` can't do anything about JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah, [`requests` can do a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14804320/9348376), but it doesn't actually load the page, and can't interact with it.