# Is it ok if my JSON data is read as List instead of Python Dictionary?

Tags: python, json, parsing

All,

I am new to JSON and python world. I'm trying to parse JSON data located [here](http://api.population.io/1.0/population/2010/United%20States/?format=json). I was able to parse JSON data using below code. My question is when I tried to check the type of my 'jsonData' object, it turned out that it is a list instead of `Dictionary`. Most of JSON data I saw online consists of type `dictionary` . So it is ok to have list as a type instead of Dictionary ? or do I need to convert my 'jsonData' object into Dictionary, if yes how can I achieve it ?

**Code for parsing**

```
response=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
json_string=response.read().decode('utf-8')
parsed_json=json.loads(json_string)
jsonData =parsed_json
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The data is a list of 101 dictionaries. If you switch on Raw Data on the website, you can see the square brackets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to the JSON and Python world. First things first, you can make the HTTP request and parse the response in fewer lines:

```
# We will use requests library instead of urllib. See Ref. 1.
import requests

url = 'http://api.population.io/1.0/population/2010/United%20States/?format=json'
response = requests.get(url) # Make an HTTP GET request
jsonData = response.json() # Read the response data in JSON format

print(type(jsonData)) # prints <type 'list'>

for x in jsonData:
    print(type(x)) # prints <type 'dict'>
```

Why does it say `jsonData` is a list? Because `jsonData` is a list.
Why does it say every `x` is a dictionary? Because every `x` is a dictionary.

Look closely at the data located [here](http://api.population.io/1.0/population/2010/United%20States/?format=json). It starts and ends with `[` and `]` respectively. Inside the `[` and `]`, there are pairs of  `{` and `}`.

```
list = [] # this is how you declare lists in python
dict = {} # this is how you declare dictionaries in python
```

So, your JSON data is being parsed correctly. It is a JSON list of JSON objects. See Ref. 2.

References:

1. [What are the differences between the urllib, urllib2, and requests module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018026/what-are-the-differences-between-the-urllib-urllib2-and-requests-module)
2. https://www.json.org