# how to read links from a list with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a list with lots of links and I want to scrape them with beautifulsoup in Python 3

links is my list and it contains hundreds of `urls`. I have tried this code to scrape them all, but it's not working for some reason

```
 links= ['http://www.nuforc.org/webreports/ndxe201904.html',
'http://www.nuforc.org/webreports/ndxe201903.html',
'http://www.nuforc.org/webreports/ndxe201902.html',
'http://www.nuforc.org/webreports/ndxe201901.html',
'http://www.nuforc.org/webreports/ndxe201812.html',
'http://www.nuforc.org/webreports/ndxe201811.html',...]

raw = urlopen(i in links).read()
ufos_doc = BeautifulSoup(raw, "html.parser")
```

Comment: Please show the contents of the list in your post.

Comment: What language or IDE are you writing this code?

Comment: I'm using Python 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`raw` should be a list containing the data of each web-page. For each entry in `raw`, parse it and create a soup object. You can store each soup object in a list (I called it `soups`):

```
links= ['http://www.nuforc.org/webreports/ndxe201904.html',
'http://www.nuforc.org/webreports/ndxe201903.html',
'http://www.nuforc.org/webreports/ndxe201902.html',
'http://www.nuforc.org/webreports/ndxe201901.html',
'http://www.nuforc.org/webreports/ndxe201812.html',
'http://www.nuforc.org/webreports/ndxe201811.html']

raw = [urlopen(i).read() for i in links]
soups = []
for page in raw:
    soups.append(BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser'))
```

You can then access eg. the soup object for the first link with `soups[0]`.

Also, for fetching the response of each URL, consider using the `requests` module instead of `urllib`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018026/what-are-the-differences-between-the-urllib-urllib2-and-requests-module).

Answer (score 0):

You need a Loop over the list links. If you have a lot of these to do, as mentioned in other answer, consider `requests`. With `requests` you can create a `Session` object which will allow you to re-use connection thereby more efficiently scraping

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

links= ['http://www.nuforc.org/webreports/ndxe201904.html',
'http://www.nuforc.org/webreports/ndxe201903.html',
'http://www.nuforc.org/webreports/ndxe201902.html',
'http://www.nuforc.org/webreports/ndxe201901.html',
'http://www.nuforc.org/webreports/ndxe201812.html',
'http://www.nuforc.org/webreports/ndxe201811.html']

with requests.Session as s:
    for link in links:
        r = s.get(link)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        #do something
```