# Converting a CURL into python script

Tags: python-3.x, curl, urllib3

I am trying to convert a Curl POST request into a python script, and i am not getting the desired output, please let me know what i am doing wrong here.

```
CURL request
 curl -s -w '%{time_starttransfer}\n' --request POST \
       --url http://localhost:81/kris/execute \
       --header 'content-type: application/json' \
       --data '{"command":["uptime"], "iplist":["10.0.0.1"], "sudo":true}'
```

This runs the uptime command in the node for which the ip is provided and returns a JSON output:

```
{"command":"uptime","output":["{\"body\":\" 17:30:06 up 60 days, 11:23,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05\\n\",\"host\":\"10.0.0.1\"}"]}0.668894
```

When i try to run the same with python, it fails and never gets the output

Code :

```
import urllib3
import json

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

payload = '{"command":["uptime"], "iplist":["10.0.0.1"], "sudo":true}'
encoded_data = json.dumps(payload)

resp = http.request(
     'POST',
     'http://localhost:81/kris/execute ',
     body=encoded_data,
     headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
print(resp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you use the [`requests` library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/). It's higher level than `urllib` and simpler to use. (For a list of reasons why it's awesome, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14804320/5021960).)

Plus it requires only minor changes to your code to work:

```py
import requests

payload = '{"command":["uptime"], "iplist":["10.0.0.1"], "sudo":true}'

resp = requests.post(
     'http://localhost:81/kris/execute',
     data=payload,
     headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
print(resp.text)
```

Note that the method `POST` is the function instead of a parameter and that is uses the named param `data` instead of `body`. It also returns a `Response` object, so you have to access its `text` property to get the actual response content.

---

Also, you don't need to `json.dumps` your string. That function is used to convert Python objects to JSON strings. The string you're using is already valid JSON, so you should just send that directly.

Comment: For some reason json.dumps(payload) is giving a Null output, when i comment encoded_data by making the changes, it works great. thank you. requests > urllib {true} .

Comment: Oh, right! It should work anyway, but the call to `json.dumps` is actually not necessary here. I updated the answer to explain that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an online utility you can check out to convert curl requests to python code.

[Curl to python converter](https://curl.trillworks.com/)

Another alternative is Postman application. There you will have the option to convert curls to code for various languages, in the code section.

It a very good practice to check if the api requests are working by running the curl in postman.

And for your case, here is the code using python requests library.

```
    import requests

headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
}

data = '{"command":["uptime"], "iplist":["10.0.0.1"], "sudo":true}'

response = requests.post('http://localhost:81/kris/execute', headers=headers, data=data)
```

Hope that helps! Happy Coding!

Comment: It seems like your link has no URL, just the parameter

Comment: @CycleOfTheAbsurd Oh yea ... fixed it now..ty!