# Diffrence between urllib.request.Request class and urllib.request..urlopen class?

Tags: python-3.x

Hey I recently saw a code which was

```
req = urllib.request.Request(mirror + path + '/q.php?q=test&cat=0',
                              headers=pirate.data.default_headers)
        try:
            f = urllib.request.urlopen(req, timeout=timeout)
```

and I wanted to know the diffrece between the Request and urlopen classes can anyone helpout?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the differences between the urllib, urllib2, urllib3 and requests module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018026/what-are-the-differences-between-the-urllib-urllib2-urllib3-and-requests-modul)

Comment: No the question u mentioned is about the difference between requests ,urllib,urllib2,urllib3 module the doubt I have is what is the difference between request and urlopen class in urllib module only