# Couldn't find urllib when using pip from desktop

Tags: python, urllib, python-3.10

When I use pip command to install 'urllib' then it shows following error. I am working on Windows 10 laptop.

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310>py -m pip install urllib
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement urllib (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for urllib

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310>pip install urllib
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement urllib (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for urllib
WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310>pip3 install urllib
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement urllib (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for urllib
WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html) is already shipped with Python, no need to install.

Answer (score 0):

It should be urllib3, not urllib. Such as:

`pip install urllib3`

Comment: Technically an unrelated package: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018026/what-are-the-differences-between-the-urllib-urllib2-urllib3-and-requests-modul

Comment: I think the OP is referring to the builtin module the ships with python

Comment: Valid, but you can't pip a builtin package, so I just assumed that OP was looking for a package he could. It's "just" a cleaned up urllib.