# Annoying Twisted Python problem

Tags: python, twisted, reactor

I'm trying to answer the following question out of personal interest:
[What is the fastest way to send 100,000 HTTP requests in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632520/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-send-100-000-http-requests-in-python)

And this is what I have came up so far, but I'm experiencing something very stange.

When **installSignalHandlers** is **True**, it just hangs. I can see that the `DelayedCall` instances are in `reactor._newTimedCalls`, but `processResponse` never gets called.

When **installSignalHandlers** is **False**, it throws an error and works.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.client import Agent
from threading import Semaphore, Thread
import time

concurrent = 100
s = Semaphore(concurrent)
reactor.suggestThreadPoolSize(concurrent)
t=Thread(
    target=reactor.run,
    kwargs={'installSignalHandlers':True})
t.daemon=True
t.start()


agent = Agent(reactor)


def processResponse(response,url):
    print response.code, url
    s.release()

def processError(response,url):
    print "error", url
    s.release()

def addTask(url):
    req = agent.request('HEAD', url)
    req.addCallback(processResponse, url)
    req.addErrback(processError, url)


for url in open('urllist.txt'):
    addTask(url.strip())    
    s.acquire()
while s._Semaphore__value!=concurrent:
    time.sleep(0.1)     

reactor.stop()
```

And here is the error that it throws when installSignalHandlers is True:
(Note: This is the expected behaviour! The question is why it doesn't work when installSignalHandlers is False.)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 396, in fireEvent
    DeferredList(beforeResults).addCallback(self._continueFiring)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 224, in addCallback
    callbackKeywords=kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 213, in addCallbacks
    self._runCallbacks()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 371, in _runCallbacks
    self.result = callback(self.result, *args, **kw)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 409, in _continueFiring
    callable(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1165, in _reallyStartRunning
    self._handleSignals()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1105, in _handleSignals
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.sigInt)
exceptions.ValueError: signal only works in main thread
```

**What am I doing wrong and what is the right way?** I'm new to twisted.

@moshez:
Thanks. It works now:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, threads
from urlparse import urlparse
import httplib
import itertools


concurrent = 100
finished=itertools.count(1)
reactor.suggestThreadPoolSize(concurrent)

def getStatus(ourl):
    url = urlparse(ourl)
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(url.netloc)   
    conn.request("HEAD", url.path)
    res = conn.getresponse()
    return res.status

def processResponse(response,url):
    print response, url
    processedOne()

def processError(error,url):
    print "error", url#, error
    processedOne()

def processedOne():
    if finished.next()==added:
        reactor.stop()

def addTask(url):
    req = threads.deferToThread(getStatus, url)
    req.addCallback(processResponse, url)
    req.addErrback(processError, url)   

added=0
for url in open('urllist.txt'):
    added+=1
    addTask(url.strip())

try:
    reactor.run()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    reactor.stop()
```

Comment: There's no reason to handle KeyboardInterrupt being raised from reactor.run().  C-c causes reactor.run() to *return*, not to raise an exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using waaaaay too much "reactor calls" (for example, there's a good chance that agent.request calls into the reactor) from the main thread. I'm not sure if that's your problem, but it's still not supported -- the only reactor calls to make from the non-reactor thread is reactor.callFromThread.

Also, the whole architecture seems strange. Why are you not running the reactor on the main thread? Reading a whole file with 10,000 requests, and splitting them, should not be a problem to do from the reactor, even if you do it all at once.

You can probably hit a pure-Twisted solution not using any threads.