# Python - Sending HTTP request at same time

Tags: python

Hey guys I have looked at the best ways to do this.  I want to make sure I understand correctly.

If I want:

http1
http2
http3
http...

To be sent at exactly the same time.  I should set these up into a thread and then start the thread?  I need to make sure it is exact same time.

I think this can be done in Java but Im not familiar with it. Thanks guys for any help you can give!

After reading up more on the process I dont think this was super clear.  Will the async processing send these packets at the same time so they arrive at the destination at the same time?  From reading different articles it seems like the async is just that.

I believe for what Im looking for, I would need to use a synchronous method like multiprocessing.

Thoughts?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I edited the question to see if I could add more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You question is not totally clear to me but have you looked at [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/)? It's an event-driven networking engine written in Python. If you're not familiar with event-driven programming, this [Linux Journal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7871) is a good introduction. Basically instead of threads, [Asynchronous I/O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_i/o) is used with the [reactor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern) (which encapsulates an event loop).

Twisted has multiple web clients. You should probably start with the newer one, called Agent (twisted.web.client.Agent), rather then the older getPage.

If you want to understand Twisted, I can recommend [Dave Peticolas's Twisted Introduction](http://krondo.com/?page_id=1327). It's long but accessible and detailed.

Comment: This seems like it should be a comment to me.

Comment: @Danny, I'm continuing to add to this answer. I wanted to get something in quickly.

Comment: My main goal is to have them sent at same time.  I have not looked at twisted,  still reading different methods but doesnt seem like many say if its possible to send at identical times.

Comment: You can do that with Twisted. It's not the only way, but if you're using Python, it's one popular way.

Comment: Any good read on twisted?  Im pretty python proficient but not an expert.

Comment: I found 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632520/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-send-100-000-http-requests-in-python 

going to read more looks like a lead.

Comment: @toyotajon93, is there anything else I can do to make this answer more acceptable to you?