# Diagnosing HTTP Request Speed

Tags: python, python-requests

I am making head requests on anywhere between 100,000 to 500,000 URLs to returns the size and the HTTP status code. I have tried four different methods: a threadpool, an asynchronous twisted client, a grequests implementation, and a concurrent.futures based solution. In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632520/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-send-100-000-http-requests-in-python) similar to this one, the threadpool implementation is said to finish in 6 to 10 minutes. Trying the exact code and feeding a dummy list of 100,000 URLs takes over 4 hours on my machine. My twisted solution (different than the one mentioned in the link question) similarly takes around 3.5 hours to complete, the same with the the concurrent.futures solution.

I am relatively confident I have written the implementations correctly, specifically in the case of copy and pasting the code from a previous example. How can I diagnose where the slow down is occurring? My guess is that it is when making the connection, but I have no idea how to prove this or fix it if it is a problem. I am pretty certain it is not a CPU bound problem, as the CPU time after 100,000 URLs is only 3 minutes. Any help in figuring out how to diagnose the issue, and in turn fixing would be greatly appreciated.

Some More Information:

- Using Requests to make the request, or treq with twisted.
- Appending the results to a list (with garbage compiler off) or a
  pandas dataframe does not seem to make a speed difference.
- I have experimented with anywhere between 4 and 200 workers/threads
  in my various tests, and 15 seems to be optimal.
- The machine I am using has 16 cores and a high speed (100 MBPS)
  internet connection.

Comment: all this on localhost ? what is the size of your thread pools ?

Comment: I have tried threadpools ranging from 50 to 200. 200 was the fastest, but still extremely slow. I have tested it on the local network mostly and it still has the speed problem.

Comment: could you post your code?

Comment: are you sure you are linking the correct question ? this one is not about threadpool.

Comment: Which one? All four options? Or just a specific one? The threadpool implementation is seen in the link above (more or less the same). I can post them all just don't want to clutter up the post.

Comment: what is the duration of each request ? (3 hours with 15 threads for 100000 should be somewhere close to 2 seconds, which is indeed a lots)

Comment: The requests start out taking about half a second each, and towards the end begin to take around 4 seconds.