# Challenge: How to send > 1000 HTTP requests in one second with Python

Tags: python, python-requests

Consider the following case: There is a slow server which use about **200ms** to handle a request (no including the network transfer time). And now, we need to send a bunch of requests every second.

After read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632520/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-send-100-000-http-requests-in-python), I have tried multi-thread, multi-process, twisted (agent.request) and eventlet. But the biggest speedup is only **6x**, which is achieved via twisted and eventlet, both are using epoll.

The following code shows the test version with eventlet,

```
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch(all=False, socket=True)

import requests

def send():
    pile = eventlet.GreenPile(30)
    for i in range(1000):
        pile.spawn(requests.get, 'https://api.???.com/', timeout=1)
    for response in pile:
        if response:
            print response.elapsed, response.text
```

Anyone could help me to make it clear why the speedup is so low? And is there any other mechanism could make it much faster?

Comment: How long does it currently take?

Comment: see if this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632520/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-send-100-000-http-requests-in-python

Comment: 1000 requests at 200ms per requests = 3,3 minutes. I don't understand why you want to overload your server. Why 1000 ? why not 1M ?

Comment: @JérômeRadix, In fact, my app is both a server and client, which will send some kinds of requests to the back-end server. Currently, 1000 is okay, 1M is also possible in future.

Comment: @Jacky You should post a job if it is challenge bro. SO is for clearing the doubts

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know this is an old post but someone might still need this.

If you want to do load testing but want to use python then you should use a tool like locust: http://locust.io/

Here is my solution which resulted in 10,000 requests in 10 seconds:

**Needed Package:**
sudo pip install grequests

**Code:**

```
import grequests
import time

start_time = time.time()
# Create a 10000 requests
urls = ['http://www.google.co.il']*10000
rs = (grequests.head(u) for u in urls)

# Send them.
grequests.map(rs)

print time.time() - start_time # Result was: 9.66666889191
```

Comment: I run the code on my laptop and got the result after 69.997563 seconds, and for 1k after 23.694893 (CPU: i7 10gen 3GHz, RAM: 16Gb,  256Gb SSD, GPU Nvidia MX230 2Gb)