# Parallel API requests in python

Tags: python, http, concurrency, urllib2

I am looking to implement the threading solution suggested here: [What is the fastest way to send 100,000 HTTP requests in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632520/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-send-100-000-http-requests-in-python)

My question is, if my "do something" after making the URL call is going to be appending a new row to a list (using data.append) - will this cause any issues?

Also, I will also be Python 2 and using urllib2 -- would the recommended solution change at all if it was urllib2 instead of httplib?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to implement IO bound operation,I would suggets you to use [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/). Here is the [example](http://www.gevent.org/intro.html#example).

Or use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24731721/4390959) answer. Gevent support not only Python 2 and Python 3, also PyPy which also can speed up your program.

Answer (score 0):

[Asynchronous IO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O) is the solution to this exact problem. Since your problem is completely IO bound there is no reason for using multiple threads. If you are using python 3.4 using [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) otherwise you can use tulips. You can also use [Trollius](http://trollius.readthedocs.org/) library which provides asyncio likes syntax in Python 2x.

Comment: do you have an example using tulips that you would recommend? I am not using python 3 so I am interested in seeing how I can apply this.

Comment: I have added the link for documentation to trollius. As an afterthought using trollius would be easier than tulips