# Concurrent download and processing of large files in python

Tags: python, concurrency, yield, coroutine, yield-from

I have a list of URLs for large files to **download** (e.g. compressed archives), which I want to **process** (e.g. decompress the archives).

Both download and processing take a long time and processing is heavy on disk IO, so I want to have **just one of each to run at a time**. Since the two tasks take about the same time and do not compete for the same resources, I want to download the next file(s) while the last is being processed.

This is a variation of the **[producer-consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem)**.

The situation is similar to [reading and processing images](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12474182/512111) or [downloading loads of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37825218/fastest-way-to-read-and-process-100-000-urls-in-python), but my downloader calls are not (yet) picklable, so I have not been able to use multiprocessing, and both tasks take about the same time.

Here is a dummy example, where both download and processing are blocking:

```
import time
import posixpath

def download(urls):
    for url in urls:
        time.sleep(3)  # this is the download (more like 1000s) 
        yield posixpath.basename(url)

def process(fname):
    time.sleep(2)  # this is the processing part (more like 600s)

urls = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for fname in download(urls):
    process(fname)
    print(fname)
```

How could I make the two tasks concurrent? Can I use `yield` or `yield from` [in a smart way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708902/in-practice-what-are-the-main-uses-for-the-new-yield-from-syntax-in-python-3), perhaps in combination with [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque)? Or must it be [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio.html) with `Future`?

Comment: Possibly Copy of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16181121/python-very-simple-multithreading-parallel-url-fetching-without-queue

Comment: No, not quite. That one is about multiple concurrent downloads. I need only one download at a time and the consumer should be aware of every new file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd simply use `threading.Thread(target=process, args=(fname,))` and start a new thread for processing.

But before that, end last processing thread :

```
t = None
for fname in download(urls):
    if t is not None: # wait for last processing thread to end
        t.join()
    t = threading.Thread(target=process, args=(fname,))
    t.start()
    print('[i] thread started for %s' % fname)
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

Comment: Cool, yes, that should work and is actually quite simple.

Comment: it should indeed, even if I coded that blind and didn't test. Please let me know if there are any issue so I can fix my answer.

Comment: I am quite sure this is a working answer, but the thing is my code is running inside some application (QGIS) that seems not to like when I use python `threading` (it crashes). I have to investigate the details but a solution based on coroutine might be safer.

Comment: I think that a `t.join()` is missing at the end of the `for` loop. Add it in a `else` clause.

Comment: I did import threading. I will try the solution outside that application and let you know if it worked. @LaurentLAPORTE that seems right. What do you say, @Loïc?

Comment: I don't think it is missing, maybe at the last pass through the loop there is no join() though the program doesn't need the thread to finish specifically.

Answer (score 1):

A year later, we are actually using Python 3's [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) and [`aiohttp`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aiohttp).