# Measuring the response's time using Tornado AsyncHTTPClient

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, tornado

I want to send GET requests to a server at fixed time intervals and log the request and response time. This interval can be in the order of tens of milliseconds. 
My first approach was to use a thread pool, as described in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2635066/2390362. I would then put a task into the queue whenever the time interval elapses and it's time to make a request. While this worked, it doesn't seem to scale too well.

I came across Tornado in this other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25549675/2390362. This seems to perform much better with heavier loads. Here's roughly how I adapted it to do what I described above.

```
import time
from tornado import ioloop, httpclient
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from functools import partial

i = 0

def handle_request(req_time, log, response):
    resp_time = datetime.now()
    log.write("%s,\t%s,\t%s,\t%s\n"%(req_time.time(), resp_time.time(), (resp_time - req_time).total_seconds(), response.code))
    global i
    i -= 1
    if i == 0:
        ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()


def do_intervals():
    http_client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
    req_count_limit = 3000
    interval = 0.01
    url = "http://www.someurl.com/"
    global i

    with open("log_file.log", 'a') as log:

        for job_counter in range(req_count_limit):

            i += 1

            req_time = datetime.now()
            current_callback = partial(handle_request, req_time, log)
            http_client.fetch(url.strip(), current_callback, method='GET')
            time.sleep(interval)
        ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    do_intervals()
```

However, I've noticed that the callback function calls only execute after all the requests have been sent, and not when the response arrives. This makes my measurement of the response time inaccurate. I just discovered Tornado and am not entirely sure how the code up there really works. Is there a way to get the response time that I'm missing, or is this the only way tornado and asynchronous HTTP works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `handle_request`, the request duration can be reasonably measured with `resp_time - req_time`.

The problem is that you're blocking the event loop with `time.sleep`, which means most of the processing doesn't make progress until the initial `for` loop completes. See [Why isn’t this example with time.sleep() running in parallel?](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/faq.html#why-isn-t-this-example-with-time-sleep-running-in-parallel)
 Try something like:

```
@gen.coroutine
def do_intervals():
    # ... existing code ...
    yield gen.sleep(interval)  # instead of time.sleep
```

Remove `IOLoop.instance().start()` from `do_intervals`.
Run it like:

```
IOLoop.instance().run_sync(do_intervals)
```

Comment: Since `yield gen.sleep(interval)` breaks out of the loop, I put the part inside the loop in a seperate `@gen.coroutine` function and used `gen.sleep()`. However it still seems to be calling the handler after all the requests are sent.

Comment: Nope, you really need to `yield gen.sleep(interval)` during the loop iteration if you want to sleep in a non-blocking manner while looping. If you decorate your `do_intervals` with `gen.coroutine` and follow the rest of my instructions it'll work as you want. I've updated my answer to be clearer.

Comment: I tried using `ioloop.PeriodicCallback` which worked but your solution seems to scale better (mine would skip some callbacks). PS: I also had to remove  the `ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()` or else I'd get a `TimeOutError`