# Should I use one worker thread per HTTP request

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests

I want to send a number of HTTP requests concurrently. I am using Python's `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` to do this. Here is the code that creates the thread pool

```
p = Pool(len(users))
```

`len(users))` is simply the number of requests.

As you can see, I am creating a thread for each request. Is this a bad idea? Should I instead create a fraction of `len(users))` threads?

Comment: Are you seeing any problems with your current approach?

Comment: Not quiet a duplicate, I don't see any rationale for choosing the number of *threads/processes/connections*, but you might like it https://stackoverflow.com/q/2632520/2823755

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd personally suggest sizing based on a multiple of `multiprocessing.cpu_count()`; this is the approach `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` goes with, using `5 * multiprocessing.cpu_count()` on the theory that threaded work blocks a lot so you want more threads than cores; if you've got a huge internet pipe, a higher multiple might make sense. You can restrict it to `min(len(users), 5 * multiprocess.cpu_count())` if you like (which avoids allocating too many threads when you don't have the tasks to saturate them).

You don't want to use a thread per task because there are limits on threads and open handles, which can occur at fairly low values on many systems, and trying to do everything at once can break that if you're talking about 10,000+ requests. Given that your internet connection likely can't benefit from parallelism beyond a certain point, you'd just be wasting resources with more threads.

Comment: I think I will use a different approach from threads actually. In python there is a thing called asyncio. I think this is like the select function in linux? The idea is that you send non-blocking requests, and then wait for any of them to be done?

Comment: @JRG: Sort of. Python has a `select` (and in modern Python, `selectors`) module that's a direct interface, but yes, the async features can do similar things (though they tend to hijack the whole program design if you use them much).