# How to throttle GET requests from a list of URLs

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, grequests

I have a list of ~250000 urls, that I need to get data from an API.

I have created a class using the grequests library to make asynchronous calls. However the API limit is 100 calls per second, which grequest surpasses.

Code using grequests:

```
import grequests

lst = ['url.com','url2.com']

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.urls = lst

    def exception(self, request, exception):
        print ("Problem: {}: {}".format(request.url, exception))

    def async(self):
        return grequests.map((grequests.get(u) for u in self.urls), exception_handler=self.exception, size=100000)


    def collate_responses(self, results):
        return [x.text for x in results]

test = Test()
#here we collect the results returned by the async function
results = test.async()
```

Is there anyway I can use the requests library to make 100 calls per second?

I tried requests, but it times out after roughly 100000 calls.

In this case I am passing an ID into the URL.

```
import requests
L = [1,2,3]

for i in L:
    #print (row)
    url = 'url.com/Id={}'.format(i)
    xml_data1 = requests.get(url).text
    lst.append(xml_data1)
    time.sleep(1)
    print(xml_data1)
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632520/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-send-100-000-http-requests-in-python) SO post might be helpful if you haven’t already seen it.

Comment: @JackMoody thank you I have, the below answer helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use multithreading.

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
def some_fun(url):
    for i in L:
    #print (row)
    url = 'url.com/Id={}'.format(i)
    xml_data1 = requests.get(url).text
    lst.append(xml_data1)
    time.sleep(1)
    print(xml_data1) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lst = ['url.com','url2.com']
    c_pool = ThreadPool(30) #add as many as threads you can
    c_pool.map(some_fun, lst)
    c_pool.close()
    c_pool.join()
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for the response. In the `some_fun` do I add the for loop? sorry still new to functions and threading

Comment: There certainly is threading in Python, but this does not use it.

Comment: @RustyShackleford, yes. That for loop must be within that function.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Can you please share references on how deploying threading? i have searched many previously and ended up with this thought. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SmashGuy sorry for the basic question, can I drop it in as is?

Comment: I have added the code @RustyShackleford. use it. It's okay to ask basic questions.

Comment: @SmashGuy thank you. There are two different things going on in your code, the `L` list is a list of IDs that I append into the URL and then I also have a list of the appended URLs in a seperate list. How can we adapt your code so that it iterates over the list of URLs versus appending an ID into the URL?

Comment: @SmashGuy should the for loop be ` for i in url_list: xml_data1 = requests.get(url).text`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178696/discussion-between-smashguy-and-rustyshackleford).