# How to send 10,000 HTTP requests concurrently using Python

Tags: python, http, concurrency

I need to get HTTP GET response from the top 1-million domains, and I want to open as much concurrent thread as possible so I can finish it faster. The only relevant post that I found is [What is the fastest way to send 100,000 HTTP requests in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632520/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-send-100-000-http-requests-in-python/2635066)
and the solution uses concurrent.futures works as expected.

However, the problem is as I am setting the number of workers higher, the performance gain seems to stagnant, i.e., I do not sense any difference if I set number of workers to 1000 or 10,000. I run it on paid EC2 instance and I can see I am only using a fraction of the available CPU and memory. Not sure what happened, is there a limit that how many concurrent thread that I can create? Can I override the limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find there isn't much difference between urllib3 and requests (requests might be a shade faster).  I would use an async library since this is a prime use case.

```
from gevent import monkey, spawn, joinall
monkey.patch_all()
import urllib3, certifi
from time import time

threads = []
url = 'https://www.google.com'
upool = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED', ca_certs=certifi.where(), num_pools=20,  block=False)

t0 = time()
for i in xrange(10000):
    threads.append(spawn(upool.request,'GET',url))

x = joinall(threads)

print len(x)
print time() - t0
```

Notice you can cap the number of connections used at once by adding `true` to `block`.

*** UPDATE FOR MULTIPROCESSING ***

```
from gevent import monkey, spawn, joinall
monkey.patch_all()
import urllib3, certifi
from time import time
import gipc

worker = {}
num_threads = 1000

def fetch(num_threads, url, cpu):
    print('starting {}'.format(cpu))
    threads = []
    upool = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED', ca_certs=certifi.where(), num_pools=20, block=False)
    t0 = time()
    for i in xrange(num_threads):
        threads.append(spawn(upool.request, 'GET', url))
    x = joinall(threads)
    return x, time() - t0

def count_cpus():
    import multiprocessing
    cpus = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    print(cpus)
    return cpus

def multicore(url):
    global worker
    with gipc.pipe() as (r,w):
        for cpu in range(count_cpus()):
            worker[str(cpu)] = gipc.start_process(target=fetch, args=(num_threads, url, cpu))
    for work in worker:
        worker[work].join()
    return worker

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multicore('https://www.google.com')

    for work in worker:
        print worker[work]
```

Comment: 10000 connections were done in 128.472000122 seconds.

Comment: I am looking at this blog: https://pawelmhm.github.io/asyncio/python/aiohttp/2016/04/22/asyncio-aiohttp.html it seems much faster than urllib, but less intuitive to comprehend.

Is it all possible to open 10,000 thread, let each of them to send a request, and then get 10,000 request done instantly?

Comment: And, I run your exact code on EC2 t3.2xlarge with 8 vCPU and 32G memory, it throw 'Device or resource Busy' error, I can only do 5000 and can finish it in about 50 seconds. What monster machine you are using to run 10000 at one time?

Comment: Keep in mind this is still single threaded.  You could leverage multiprocesses on top of this to leverage more cpu's.

Comment: Can you give me a hint how? I am not expert on multi-thread or process programmer but just want the job done. I know the clumsy way is to manually type and run the command twice in Linux then it indeed runs 2 times faster. But is there an intuitive and easy way to accomplish it with Python?

Comment: I actually use this in production: https://github.com/jgehrcke/gipc  gipc

Comment: I gave an example