# How can I optimize this code? Concurrent requests with python (concurrent library)

Tags: python, performance, optimization, concurrency, python-requests

I am creating an endpoint in my API (FastAPI) that needs to send multiple requests to an external API with very large responses. The external API is paginated, and I need to get all the pages and return them within my API. Generally is 15-25 requests out to the external API which can take up to 60 seconds with my current implementation. I am wondering if there is a better library (ex: asyncio) or a different implementation to potentially reduce the response time in my endpoint.

Here is the current (simplified) implementation I have:

```
def load_url(url, page, parameters):
    parameters["page"] = page
    try:
        response = requests.get(url=url, params=parameters)
        return response
    except Exception as e:
        # handle exception

def get_response(total_page_number, url, parameters):
    items = []
    CONNECTIONS = 100
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=CONNECTIONS) as executor:
        future_to_url = (
            executor.submit(load_url, url, page, parameters)
            for page in range(1, total_page_number + 1)
        )
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
            try:
                data = future.result()
            except Exception as exc:
                # handle exception
                print(exc)
            finally:
                items += data

    return items
```

Initially I was doing the requests one by one and this was (predictably) slower. (60s average for one by one, 36s average for this current solution) Wondering if i'm doing something wrong and would really appreciate some guidance on this.

(This code was taken and modified from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632520/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-send-100-000-http-requests-in-python) on stack overflow which was a different use case (Was only sending head requests) )

Comment: Unless you have 20+ CPUs on your platform, you may have specified too many workers. Try constructing ThreadPoolExecutor **without** specifying *max_workers*

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I went ahead and removed max_workers but the response time was about the same.

Comment: You're just returning the `requests.Response` here, not the response data (or parsing it) – have you profiled your code to see where time is actually being spent? I'd suspect it's in e.g. `json.loads()`.

Comment: I set timers from when the request starts to when it ends and that's definitely the part that's taking time - seems like the json.loads() is pretty trivial in terms of time.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code and execute time response because I dont have your url that you run. It a I/O bound task, so I use `aiohttp`.

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

async def load_url(client, url, header, page, parameters):
    parameters["page"] = page
    resp = await client.get(url, headers=header, params=parameters, timeout=300)
    if resp.status != 200:
        raise Exception(resp.text)
    data = await resp.json()
    return data

async def add_task(parameters, url, header, total_page_number):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(
        connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(force_close=True, limit=50)
    ) as client:
        tasks = []
        for page in range(1, total_page_number + 1):
            tasks.append(
                asyncio.ensure_future(
                    load_url(client, url, header, page, parameters)
                )
            )
        list_result = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return list_result

def get_response(parameters, url, header, total_page_number):
    return asyncio.run(add_task(parameters, url, header, total_page_number))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - I tried this and had the same response time. Do we not need to call get_response with async / await? Also wondering if I need to change my endpoint implementation to be an async endpoint?

Comment: @serp002 yes, you should use async endpoint with your api can be many called by client. If you a wsgi for production such as gunicorn, you can change type worker and scale by number worker without use multiprocess to scale api

Comment: Note that if you're running this in an async context to begin with, you shouldn't (and can't) use `asyncio.run()`. Also, `httpx` is an async-friendly alternative to `aiohttp`; I haven't measured if either is faster or slower, just throwing that out there.