# check if url exist at fanfiction.net

Tags: python, httplib

I am trying to find out the last chapter number of a story at www.fanfiction.net just for fun. For this I thought that since it has a fixed pattern of url I will just increment the chapter number till the time that it gives me a url which does not exist.

To find whether the url existed I tried out the script at this [stackoverflow ques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471275/python-script-to-see-if-a-web-page-exists-without-downloading-the-whole-page)

However i found out that it does not give a response error of > 400 and rather gives a message along with 200 response. What would be the best way to identify that the page exists or not.

Here is a link that actually exists [exists](http://www.fanfiction.net/s/6335709/2/Harry_Potter_Choosing_Sides) and here is one that does not exist [does not exist](http://www.fanfiction.net/s/6335709/20/Harry_Potter_Choosing_Sides)

How can i do so ?

## EDIT 1

Thanks to GregSchoen I worked it out. I hope it is correct though :)

I checked out the values for resp.getheader("last-modified", None) and it gives some date for active links and None for those which are not.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Or you could fetch the first chapter, look for a `select` tag with `name="chapter"`, and read the `value` of each `option` element it contains to get a list of chapters.  You could use `BeautifulSoup` to parse the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do a HEAD request on the URLs you supplied, Last-Modified is set on valid pages but not on invalid pages. This would be an easy way to key on valid pages, since their server is not responding with a proper HTTP code.

Comment: Hey could you explain some more ... how can i check for the last modified variable in the header ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use cURL, read 100 bytes and just look for "FanFiction.Net Message Type 1" at the start of the data?

Answer (score 0):

That website isn't giving a `404` error, which renders all of those scripts useless. You will need to download the whole webpage and check whether it looks like a `404` page.

I think just running:

```
if (page.find('<style>') == 0):
```

does the trick, as the page begins with a `<style>` tag (a normal page shouldn't).

Comment: could it be done by any other method than downloading the whole page because I was thinking of increasing incrementally the page number and seeing if it exists....

Comment: Not really, as the `404` message (not found) isn't given. Instead, the `200` message (success) is given. You have to download the page and check whether it's the error page or not...